# Deleting Python modules

Tags: python

Can you delete Python modules? I've installed one that I would like to remove, and can't seem to figure out how.

Thanks

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?  And which specific module/package was it?  And what platform are you on (if that's not going to be obvious after you update your question)?

Answer (score 37):

To find where the module is, just do a:

```
 $ python
 >> import module
 >> print module.__file__
 '/some/directory'
```

or if it is a package:

```
 >> import package
 >> print package.__path__
```

and delete it.

Comment: Even easier: I've never seen "print module" fail to properly display it's location, whether module, package, inside zip file, etc.

Comment: A python library may also install standalone scripts which would be placed in other directories.

Comment: With python3 don't forget the brackets: print(module.__file__)

Comment: i really needed this to uninstall `subprocess.run` , thanks al lot

Answer (score 18):

If you are using python under windows, the following command is what you need

```
pip uninstall module
```

In some cases, you may have installed different versions of the module. For example, after I had the lxml3.4.4 installed via pip, I also installed lxml3.5.0 using its pre-built binary, and thus, the command listed above only remove the first one. So I need to run it twices

```
pip uninstall lxml
pip uninstall lxml
```

And it got completed uninstalled. See whether it helps.

Answer (score 5):

This has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall).

Go into the "site-packages" directory of your python install and remove the files manually.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using -m flag (especially if Alex Feng's answer is not working) is:

```
python -m pip uninstall module
```

NOTE: This works only for Windows, and is to be run in the Command Prompt.
To see if the module has been uninstalled, simply try to import the module again.