# If i unsinstall python then will it also uninstall downloaded packages?

Tags: python, package, uninstallation

So, i recently used sublime text for python code and i couldnt run code because i forgot to check mark the 'add to path' option, i thought to just reinstall python properly. But i have downloaded some libraries from pip will they also be removed completely if i delete/uninstall python?

surprisingly no one has asked this Q on stackoverflow as i didnt find any.

**Also:** i came across this link while searching for my question which was about [packages/modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501746/deleting-python-modules#2501894). Is there a difference between library/packages/modules? i thought the words were used interchangeably but the code syntax suggests otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer, but here is a work-around:

**Get all currently installed packages and store them in a file**

`pip freeze > current.txt`

Then you can uninstall Python.

Next step would be to re-install Python, followed by re-installing your packages.

`pip install -r current.txt`

The packages would either be installed again, or a message will be raised stating the package is already installed (i.e. requirement already satisfied)

Comment: i see. by the way i thought why not just uninstall and see what happens and after re-installing i used `pip list` and all the libraries i downloaded were there along with their requirement/dependent libraries too. is that how pip worked before, im not sure. i had installed(and re-installed) python 3.8.5, just so you know.