# Does pip uninstall modules?

Tags: python, windows, pip

I checked the installed modules with `help("modules")`

I've tried uninstalling a module I did not want with `pip uninstall somemodule`, but I got this warning:

`WARNING: Skipping somemodule as it is not installed.`

In [pip's documentation of pip uninstall](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_uninstall/) it says in the description: *Uninstall packages*.

However in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501746/deleting-python-modules/35555865#35555865) it says that running `pip uninstall somemodule` will work.

**Question:**

1. Can `pip` uninstall modules or only packages? I'm very confused.
2. Will deleting the `.py` file in its directory, completely uninstall it, or is it a bad practice?

EDIT:

> I have 2 versions of python installed. I ran all commands in python 3.9.1

> `py --version` gives `Python 3.9.1`, and `pip --version` gives `pip 21.0.1 from c:\...\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.9)`

> I've created a `venv` at some point. I deleted the folder shortly after creating the `venv`.

> `py -m pip uninstall somemodule` also did not work

> `somemodule` is the `antigravity` module that comes with python

Comment: you should use `pip uninstall` to remove modules as you previously did. Also, check in case you have multiple versions of python installed or maybe even a virtualenv as I think this may be the reason why the module is not uninstalled

Comment: are you sure your python's environment running pip is the same as the environment where you ran help("modules") ?

Comment: To elaborate on @Titouan answer, check that the interpreter in `pip --version` and `python --version` match. Given the transition from `python2` to `python3`, `python` may point to `python3` but `pip` usually points to `pip2` instead of `pip3` (or vice versa).

Comment: @ZeroPancakes First of all, `pip` installs or uninstalls distributions which happens to delete the associated packages and modules. What did you try to uninstall (i.e. what did you insert for `somemodule`)? Does `python -m pip uninstall ...` work?

Comment: the problem may be someone's design decision, which allows you to install library `pillow` but import `PIL`. So when you try to uninstall `PIL` you will have to uninstall `pillow` otherwise pip will complain about missing module

Answer (score 1):

With `pip` you can [install](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/) or uninstall [distribution packages](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-Distribution-Package). These may contain any number of [packages](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-Import-Package), [modules](https://packaging.python.org/glossary/#term-Module) or resource files. The [`antigravity`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/antigravity.py) module however is part of the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) and hence cannot be removed by `pip`. If you really want to remove that module, you can identify its location in the following way and then remove it manually:

```
>>> import antigravity
>>> antigravity.__file__
'/path/to/lib/python3.9/antigravity.py'
$ rm lib/python3.9/antigravity.py
```

You can get a list of installed distributions via `pip freeze` and these are the ones you can remove as well. Note that sometimes the distribution name and the name of the top-level package that you import are not the same (e.g. you would do `pip install scikit-learn` and then `import sklearn`).