# Combine --user with --prefix error with setup.py install

Tags: python, installation, distutils

I was trying to install Python packages a system I recently gained access to. I was trying to take advantage of Python's relatively new [per user site-packages directory](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-370-per-user-site-packages-directory), and the new option `--user`. (The option is [currently undocumented](http://bugs.python.org/issue10745), however it exists for Python 2.6+; you can see the help by running `python setup.py install --help`.)

When I tried running

```
python setup.py install --user
```

on any package I downloaded, I always got the following error:

```
error: can't combine user with with prefix/exec_prefix/home or install_(plat)base
```

The error was extremely perplexing because, as you can see, I wasn't providing the `--prefix`, `--exec-prefix`, `--install-base`, or `--install-platbase` flags as command line options. I wasted a lot of time trying to figure out what the problem was. I document my answer below, in hopes to spare some other poor soul a few hours of [yak shaving](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yak_shaving).

Comment: I got the same error trying to install python 3.6 from source with `./configure --prefix=${HOME}` while having "user=1" in `~/.pydistutils.cfg`.
In that case, I need to temporary comment "user=1" so that the installation process can complete.

Comment: bli gave a good hint.  I was wondering where the --user option is coming from even I did not use that option.   pip install --prefix /home/myhomedir.  I don't have the ~/.pydistutils.cfg file, still looking for where --user option is set.

Comment: Figure out the source of the problem. This is Debian-specific.  After adding --system option to pip the problem went away.

Comment: @KeminZhou This --system option fixed so many pip install issues for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 173, accepted):

## One time workaround:

```
pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" <package_name>
```

or

```
python setup.py install --user --prefix=
```

Note that there is no text (not even whitespace) after the `=`.

Do *not* forget the `--user` flag.

## Installing multiple packages:

Create `~/.pydistutils.cfg` (or equivalent for your OS/platform) with the following contents:

```
[install]
prefix=
```

Note that there is no text (not even whitespace) after the `=`.

Then run the necessary `pip install --user` or `python setup.py install --user` commands. Do *not* forget the `--user` flag.

Finally, remove or rename this file. Leaving this file present will cause issues when installing Python packages system-wide (i.e., without `--user`) as this user with this `~/.pydistutils.cfg`.

## The cause of this issue

This appears to be an issue with both OpenSUSE and RedHat, which has lead to [a bug in virtualenv](https://bugs.launchpad.net/virtualenv/+bug/248558) on these platforms.

The error stems from a system-level [distutils configuration file](http://docs.python.org/install/index.html#distutils-configuration-files) (in my case `/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/distutils.cfg`) where there was this

```
[install]
prefix=/usr/local
```

Basically, this is equivalent to always running the install command as `install --prefix=/usr/local`. You have to override this specification using one of the techniques above.

Comment: Thank you very much. The empty prefix fixed my problem: pip 1.1 openSuSE 11.4.

Comment: You could also pass a empty --prefix= to setup.py in the command line to override the value in the system-wide distutils.cfg

Comment: Wow! This worked for me too. I received the same error when trying to install Powerline. https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation/osx.html#i-receive-an-importerror-when-trying-to-use-powerline-on-os-x

Comment: On second thought, doing this will cause MAJOR problems. DO NOT keep this file around. See brew doctor for more info (assuming you're using homebrew on Mac OS X).

Comment: @A-Dubb is right, this can cause major issues. unfortunately brew doctor isn't helping me

Comment: Note that keeping this file like this will make Python think that / is your root python library directory, leading to confusing issues if you try to install other new packages.

Comment: run `python setup.py install --user --prefix=`. I couldn't edit `/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/distutils.cfg`

Comment: I faced this issue in osx also. It helped me on time. Thx.

Comment: I am trying to build packages with pip --target for AWS Lambda. But with '--target' this error persists.

Comment: In my case what worked was a simple "upgrade pip" since I was building a docker container based on a snapcore/snapcraft image that was carrying pip8. So, upgrading to pip 20 did the trick

Answer (score 7):

Posting to save others time, as no available answers worked for me...

In some environments, using the `--target` (`-t`) switch will still hit the same error. In my testing on two flavors of linux, I encountered the same issue when using the `--prefix=` parameter.

Code:

```
PYTHONUSERBASE=/tmp/ pip install --user --force-reinstall $PACKAGE
```

Explanation:
My workaround, which seems to work across many environments (MacOS, Amazon Linux, Debian) is to set the `PYTHONUSERBASE` environment variable to a temp location.  `--force-reinstall` is used to trigger the local installation even when the package is already installed.

This will result in the module being compiled/installed (depending on the OS and Python version) to: `/tmp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/*`

Answer (score 6):

As has been noted in the comments, the accepted answer (by @gotgenes, who, presumably, has genes) can lead to unexpected consequences.

@rogeleaderr says, "Note that keeping this file like this will make Python think that / is your root python library directory, leading to confusing issues if you try to install other new packages."

Rather than write a new config file, as @gotgenes recommends, a better option is to add `--prefix=`  (with no text to the right of the equals sign) as an option on the *command line*, as in

```
$ python setup.py install --user --prefix=
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply run `pip install --user .` , no prefix args required.

This is better anyway because it will default to python3 if your pip is configured to use Python 3.
(I forgot to enter `python3 setup.py` and it installed a 3-only package under 2.7)

(credit https://stackoverflow.com/a/1550235/4364036)

Answer (score 1):

I had have the same problem. It was hidden inside the `~/.config/pip/pip.conf` with:

```
[global]
target=/foo/bar
```

Such a config was created by a third-party script without my knowledge.

**I suggest** checking the pip configuration files and removing the `target=/foo/bar` options.

Answer (score 0):

The following didn't work for me:

```
pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" <package_name>
```

However, when using it with `sudo`, it works:

```
sudo pip install --user --install-option="--prefix=" <package_name>
```

Thanks to [gotgenes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38140/gotgenes) for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495120/combine-user-with-prefix-error-with-setup-py-install/4495175#4495175)

Comment: Of course using `sudo` it will work. It will also polute/break the OS package management.