# How can I install the python module YAML without ROOT ACCESS ( 'easy_install' and 'pip' are not available)?

Tags: python, installation, pyyaml, root-access

I am trying to run a python script that calls the **yaml module** on a server.  I only have writing permissions in my home directory. The server has Python 2.7.3 installed. I do not have root access. Also, neither **pip** nor **easy_install** are available.

I have downloaded the package and tried to run

```
python setup.py install --user
```

which gives the error

```
error: can't combine user with with prefix/exec_prefix/home or install_(plat)base
```

How  can I get this to work?

Comment: The only thing I can think of would be a virtualenv. I don't have root, but I made a virtualenv and added symlinks `mypip` and `mython` to `~/bin`, now I have my own python installation with pip, and every module I could hope for!  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! What I ended up doing was download [`virtualenv.py`](https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py) and simply run that specifying a folder `python virtualenv.py MYFOLDER`

Comment: This has the same error and a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495120/combine-user-with-prefix-error-with-setup-py-install

Answer (score 0):

Setting up and using a virtualenv is almost always a good option and as you indicated you can download [virtualenv.py](https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py), but that won't run (anymore) without `pip` being installed because it tries to install wheels. On Linux Mint with Python 2.7.6 the script e.g. throws:

> OSError: Command /home/ruamel/venv/bin/python -c "import sys, pip; sys...d\"] + sys.argv[1:]))" setuptools wheel failed with error code 1

You can probably circumvent that by using an older `virtualenv.py`.

In some other cases it is not feasible to use a virtualenv: e.g. when the system python has all kinds of libraries pre-installed that you need to use and cannot replicate into a local virtualenv. In that case you can download the latest version of [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml) (of which I am the author) and which is essentially a superset of the PyYAML functionality. When I forked the code I created a setup.py from scratch and it allows you to do

```
python setup.py install --user
```

without problem on the `setup.py extracted from the tar.gz file downloaded from PyPI.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea of the answer by Anton, these steps worked for me

```
pip install --user ruamel.yaml
```

then replace in your script

```
import yaml
```

with:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml=YAML(typ='safe')
```