# installing PyYAML and libyaml without root or sudo

Tags: linux, python-2.7, yaml, pyyaml, libyaml

I need to setup PyYAML with the libyaml bindings.
I'm working on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client with release 5.7 and I have a local copy of Enthought Python 7.3.2 installed under `/tools/Devel/epd_free-7.3-2rh5-x86_64`
and have added `/tools/Devel/epd_free-7.3-2rh5-x86_64/bin` to $PATH

I'm working on this local copy since I don't have root or sudo access on the machine.

To install libyaml I have done:

```
tar -xvzf yaml-0.1.5.tar.gz
cd yaml-0.1.5
./configure prefix=/tools/Devel/epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64
make
make install
```

which has created

```
/tools/Devel/epd_free-7.3-2rh5-x86_64/include/yaml.h
```

as well as

```
/tools/Devel/epd_free-7.3-2rh5-x86_64/lib/libyaml-0.so.2
/tools/Devel/epd_free-7.3-2rh5-x86_64/lib/libyaml-0.so.2.0.3
/tools/Devel/epd_free-7.3-2rh5-x86_64/lib/libyaml.a
/tools/Devel/epd_free-7.3-2rh5-x86_64/lib/libyaml.la
/tools/Devel/epd_free-7.3-2rh5-x86_64/lib/libyaml.so
/tools/Devel/epd_free-7.3-2rh5-x86_64/lib/pkgconfig
```

However when I try to install PyYAML I get

```
pip install PyYAML

Downloading/unpacking PyYAML
  Downloading PyYAML-3.11.tar.gz (248kB): 248kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_greglac/PyYAML/setup.py) egg_info for package PyYAML

Installing collected packages: PyYAML
  Running setup.py install for PyYAML
    checking if libyaml is compilable
    gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -O2 -fPIC -I/tools/Devel/epd_free-7.3-2-rh5-x86_64/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.o
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c:2:18: error: yaml.h: No such file or directory
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c: In function âmainâ:
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c:5: error: âyaml_parser_tâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c:5: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c:5: error: for each function it appears in.)
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c:5: error: expected â;â before âparserâ
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c:6: error: âyaml_emitter_tâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c:6: error: expected â;â before âemitterâ
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c:8: error: âparserâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/check_libyaml.c:11: error: âemitterâ undeclared (first use in this function)

    libyaml is not found or a compiler error: forcing --without-libyaml
    (if libyaml is installed correctly, you may need to
     specify the option --include-dirs or uncomment and
     modify the parameter include_dirs in setup.cfg)

Successfully installed PyYAML
Cleaning up...
```

I assume this is because PyYAML is looking for libyaml in the default location. Is there away to specify the location of libyaml for the pyyaml install?

Answer (score 0):

use https://pypi.python.org/simple/pyyaml/ and downloading PyYAML-3.11.tar.gz worked for me in windows

then i extracted it and after opening i wrote the command setup.py install in this location

for other packages search in https://pypi.python.org/simple

Answer (score 0):

Based on the idea of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866392/how-can-i-install-the-python-module-yaml-without-root-access-easy-install-an/45058313#45058313) these steps worked for me

```
pip install --user ruamel.yaml
```

then replace in your script

```
import yaml
```

with:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
yaml=YAML(typ='safe')
```