# ipython: command not found on OSX

Tags: macos, pip, ipython, homebrew

I installed the python scientific environment (numpy, scipy, matplotlib, pandas, ipython) a while ago on OSX using brew and either pip or easy_install (or the 2 of them, I don't remember). Now if try to run ipython I get:

```
-> ipython
-bash: ipython: command not found
```

Then I did:

```
-> sudo find . -iname "*ipython*"
Password:
find: ./dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: ./dev/fd/4: Not a directory
./Users/jfk/.ipython
./usr/local/Cellar/matplotlib/1.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/sphinxext/ipython_console_highlighting.py
./usr/local/Cellar/matplotlib/1.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/sphinxext/ipython_console_highlighting.pyc
./usr/local/Cellar/matplotlib/1.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/sphinxext/ipython_directive.py
./usr/local/Cellar/matplotlib/1.2.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/sphinxext/ipython_directive.pyc
./usr/local/Cellar/matplotlib/1.2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/sphinxext/ipython_console_highlighting.py
./usr/local/Cellar/matplotlib/1.2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/sphinxext/ipython_console_highlighting.pyc
./usr/local/Cellar/matplotlib/1.2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/sphinxext/ipython_directive.py
./usr/local/Cellar/matplotlib/1.2.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/sphinxext/ipython_directive.pyc
./usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share/doc/ipython
./usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share/doc/ipython/examples/core/ipython-get-history.py
./usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share/doc/ipython/examples/core/ipython-qtconsole.desktop
./usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share/doc/ipython/examples/core/ipython-sh.desktop
./usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share/doc/ipython/examples/core/ipython.desktop
./usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share/doc/ipython/examples/core/ipython_here_shell_extension.reg
./usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/share/man/man1/ipython.1
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/profile/cluster/ipython_config.py
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/profile/cluster/ipython_config.pyc
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/profile/math/ipython_config.py
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/profile/math/ipython_config.pyc
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/profile/pysh/ipython_config.py
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/profile/pysh/ipython_config.pyc
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/profile/sympy/ipython_config.py
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/profile/sympy/ipython_config.pyc
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/html/notebook/static/codemirror/README-IPython.rst
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/html/notebook/static/codemirror/theme/ipython.css
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/qt/console/ipython_widget.py
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/qt/console/ipython_widget.pyc
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/qt/console/resources/icon/IPythonConsole.svg
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/qt/console/rich_ipython_widget.py
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/frontend/qt/console/rich_ipython_widget.pyc
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.2-py2.7.egg-info
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/sphinxext/ipython_console_highlighting.py
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/sphinxext/ipython_console_highlighting.pyc
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/sphinxext/ipython_directive.py
./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/sphinxext/ipython_directive.pyc
./usr/local/share/python/ipython
```

I was surprised not to see any /bin directory.

Then I tried to reinstall ipython

```
-> pip install ipython
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Cleaning up...
```

This is really confusing. Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that ``pip`` that you call belongs to Homebrew's Python? From your file list it seems that you have installed ``ipython`` in your system Python, so it has put the executable into ``/usr/local/share/python``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create `.pydistutils.cfg` in your `$HOME` following contents

```
[global]
verbose=1

[install]
install-scripts=$HOME/bin

[easy_install]
install-scripts=$HOME/bin
```

Run

```
pip install -U --user --force ipython
```

Have a look at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/426

Comment: your suggestion lead to `error: can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base`. I was able to correct it using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495120/combine-user-with-prefix-error-with-setup-py-install. Now ipython is working normally.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround (at least for ipython) is to add these lines to `~/.pydistutils.cfg`:

`[install]
install-data=/usr/local
install-scripts=/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

save the code in the executable file `python3` under the path `/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin` (change to our python version)

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python@3.10/bin/python3.10
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from IPython import start_ipython
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
```