# iPython installed but not found

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I've recently deleted Anaconda and reinstalled python with brew. I've installed everything according to [these](https://joernhees.de/blog/2014/02/25/scientific-python-on-mac-os-x-10-9-with-homebrew/) instructions.

Python works great, and all packages I've tested so far also work. I've got ipython installed, but trying to launch it from the terminal gives:

> -bash: ipython: command not found

I've located the installation at:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython

Following older related questions, I've tried adding this path to .bash_profile but got:

> -bash: :/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython: No such file or directory

Whenever terminal starts.

Some more info: Anaconda installed an removed, El-Capitan 10.11.2, python 2.7.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: added some more info to @cel request:

`echo $PATH` gives:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin
```

`which -a python` gives:
`/usr/local/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python`.

EDIT: added the output of `python -m pip install ipython` to cel's request:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): traitlets in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pickleshare in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): simplegeneric>0.8 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): decorator in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): gnureadline in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): appnope in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pexpect in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython-genutils in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from traitlets->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): path.py in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pickleshare->ipython)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ptyprocess>=0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pexpect->ipython)
```

Comment: You may want to remove `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython` from your path again. This is not how the `PATH` variable works. After that, please restart your terminal, and add the output of `echo $PATH` and  `which -a python` to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I removed it from .bash_profile (I assume this is what you meant), restarted terminal and ipython still doesn't work. `echo $PATH` gives: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin`  and `which -a python` gives: `/usr/local/bin/python` and `/usr/bin/python`.

Comment: You can install ipython via `python -m pip install ipython`, after that you should be able to start ipython from command line.

Comment: I just tried - got a bunch of `Requirement already satisfied` (I can attach if you think it might help), after which I got the same `-bash: ipython: command not found` from before...

Comment: Yes, the output would be helpful.

Comment: added the output of `python -m pip install ipython` to the original question.

Comment: For those who are trying to add ipython to PATH on Windows, the executable may be under the path "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<version>\Scripts". Adding this folder to PATH (using `setx path "%PATH%;C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python<version>\Scripts"`) allowed me to launch ipython from the terminal by running `ipython`.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Searching the web for `"bash: ipython: command not found"` turns up several hits (including [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856194/ipython-on-macos-10-10-command-not-found)), but they're not particularly helpful. From the sound of it, you have `IPython`, the Python *package* installed, but `ipython`—the *entry point* (i.e., wrapper/launcher script) for it—is missing for whatever reason. To check whether this is the case, try running:

```
% python -m IPython
Python 2.7.9 (default, Feb 10 2015, 03:28:08) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]:
```

If that brings up IPython, then you might try making a shell alias as the SO answer linked above suggests, i.e., put something like this in your shell's startup script: `alias ipython='python -m IPython'`. Or, create the launcher script yourself. For me, it lives in `/usr/local/bin/ipython` and contains the following:

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from IPython import start_ipython

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(start_ipython())
```

<sup>If this helps, please consider up-voting the other SO *question* as well...</sup>

**UPDATE**: Here are some more possibly-relevant links:

- [ipython: command not found on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18264908/99127)
- https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/426

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed a wrapper/launcher issue, and was resolved by adding `alias ipython='python -m IPython'` to `.bash_profile`. Upvoted the question you referred to as well.

Comment: @GoingMyWay probably because python sees `IPython` as a module somehow

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, try adding `alias ipython='python3 -m IPython'` to `.bash_profile`.

Comment: as @parth92 writes in his answer, your solution only works for a little amount of packages. For both solutions, alias and launcher script, you have to address each package. I need a global, more dynamic solution.

Comment: `alias ipython='python -m IPython'` in self-created `.bashrc` - file using `MINGW64` - git-bash on `Windows 10` did it for me.

Comment: I use `windows` 10, `Python app` from the store and `wsl2`. I get no output with `python3.exe` and `which python3` throws `/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.exe`. In `path` I have `../mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps`. Is it a new question or can you help?

Answer (score 20):

The answer given by @evadeflow does the job, but there are several other packages installed with pip and it will be very uncomfortable to keep adding `alias` for each of them.
A rather elegant way would be to add the path where these packages are installed to the `$PATH` variable. In my case adding the following line in ~/.bashrc did the job:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/my_user_name/.local/bin
```

Addl refs: https://askubuntu.com/q/551990/632996; https://askubuntu.com/q/556090

Comment: Your intensions are good yet your provide a solution to a problem that does not exist. The OP reported that  "Python works great, and all packages [...] tested so far also work".

Comment: Didn't get you.. We are talking about ipython, right?
Python was working great in my case as well.

Comment: This answer *is* useful, because in my case pip installed the ipython launcher into `~/.local/bin` which wasn't in my `PATH`. That is the root cause of why `ipython` wasn't a valid command.

Comment: In my case, this step of adding the installed path to the $PATH variable was done automatically by the python3.7 OSX installer I downloaded from python.org -- there was a file `~/.bash_profile` created which did this. When I read this answer I checked to see what my `~/.bashrc` looked like (new computer) and saw that I just had to `source ~/.bash_profile` to get the path to update.

Comment: meanwhile `ipython notebook` has been deprecated. if you have made it up to this point, try `jupyter notebook` instead.

Answer (score 13):

What worked for me was to unistall using:

```
~pip3 uninstall ipython
```

and then:

```
~sudo pip3 install ipython
```

I'm running this on (W10)WSL2 with a Debian.

Comment: This worked for me. IPython was installed to `.local/bin` but I'm using a conda env so it should not redirect here. I had t uninstall it from `.local/bin` and reinstall it in my conda env. Thanks!

Comment: worked for me as well in Ubuntu

Answer (score 7):

for python3

`python3 -m IPython`

Comment: Why not alias `python` to use Python 3 instead? Python 2 has been sunset as of 2020.

Answer (score 4):

If working with **Python3**, just try:

```
ipython3
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you just need to source your bash_profile after you successfully installed anaconda.

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: That's because it will add `~/.local/bin` to PATH.

Answer (score 0):

For anaconda users:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets
```

Answer (score 0):

for most people:

```
pip install ipython
```

for those who need mirror (if installation is very slow)

```
pip install ipython -i http://pypi.douban.com/simple/ --trusted-host pypi.douban.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apple Silicon Macbook, mostly you are using zsh now. So for me the following worked.

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Quit the terminal after this, and open it back and try.
Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

I installed ipython using apt in Ubuntu 18.04 as follows:

```
sudo apt install python-ipython
```

Then, the 'ipython' command didn't work and I got the same "Command not found" error mentioned above. The same happened after installed python3-python. However, then I tried `sudo apt install ipython` and the correct wrappers were installed. I don't know if something similar happens with pip, but that is my experience with apt.