# Installed anaconda but can't find ipython, pandas etc

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, ipython

I have installed anaconda by following the instruction on
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os
On Mac OS 10.13.6
However, when I open iTerm2 and try launching ipython, the shell will complain

```
zsh: command not found: ipython
```

Can't open regular python shell and `import pandas` either. Even `conda` itself is not found. I'm guessing it's a path problem? But I am not sure where is the default path for conda related libs.

Comment: Ah I see, maybe I should add `/Users/myusername/anaconda3/bin` to PATH.

Comment: probably this will help you, If not above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441943/ipython-installed-but-not-found  @clwen