# ipython installed, but not found

Tags: python, ipython, oh-my-zsh

Below is the text from the zsh terminal, ipython installed but not found. Need help. Cant unintstall because it can't be found. Can't run because it can't be found. But according to bash it's there.

```
➜  green ipython
zsh: command not found: ipython
➜  green ipython3
zsh: command not found: ipython3
➜  green ipython --version
zsh: command not found: ipython
➜  green ipython3 --version
zsh: command not found: ipython3
➜  green pip3 install ipython
Requirement already satisfied: ipython in /home/joshuamwolfe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (7.18.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect>4.3; sys_platform != "win32" in /home/joshuamwolfe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: prompt-toolkit!=3.0.0,!=3.0.1,<3.1.0,>=2.0.0 in /home/joshuamwolfe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (3.0.7)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.2 in /home/joshuamwolfe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (5.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipython) (45.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator in /home/joshuamwolfe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: jedi>=0.10 in /home/joshuamwolfe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (0.17.2)
Requirement already satisfied: backcall in /home/joshuamwolfe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (0.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pickleshare in /home/joshuamwolfe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (0.7.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pygments in /home/joshuamwolfe/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ipython) (2.7.1)
```

update:

The solution that worked.... /facepalm

sudo pip3 instal ipython

```
➜  ~ sudo pip3 install ipython
Collecting ipython
Successfully installed backcall-0.2.0 decorator-4.4.2 ipython-7.18.1 ipython-genutils-0.2.0 jedi-0.17.2 parso-0.7.1 pexpect-4.8.0 pickleshare-0.7.5 prompt-toolkit-3.0.7 ptyprocess-0.6.0 pygments-2.7.1 traitlets-5.0.4 wcwidth-0.2.5
➜  ~ ipython
Python 3.8.2 (default, Jul 16 2020, 14:00:26)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 7.18.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:
```

[iPython installed but not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441943/ipython-installed-but-not-found)

Reasons I didn't go with the above link as the solution:

- The main reason was, % python -m IPython, did respond, zsh thought it wasnt installed.
- I was using oh my zosh.
- The +5 answer by: Parth92, gave me pause for concern.

Comment: 1) This is zsh and not bash. 2) ipython is installed in your home folder, which most likely isn't in your PATH, so you'd either have to uninstall it and install as root, call it via explicit path or add the folder to your PATH

Comment: Alrighty. I'll give it a whirl.

Comment: As a noob, what's the best option here?

Comment: I would probably go with a system wide install (`sudo pip3 install ipython3`), because you won't have to fiddle with anything using that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPython installed but not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34441943/ipython-installed-but-not-found)

Comment: I saw that thread, but 100% of what it all meant, that's why I created this one. It turns out, that it needed to be installed globally. Recent convert to WSL2. I don't remember installing it. For whatever reason the systemwide install recommended a couple of responses up did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Install globally if you're a beginner, fewer chances for mistakes.

```
sudo pip3 install ipython3
```

Answer (score 2):

Same thing here with Debian Buster, I put `~/.local/bin` in my `PATH` and it works well.
So, after installing ipython with `pip install ipython` command, add this line to your `~/.profile` :

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/.local/bin/"
```

You might need to source your `.profile` first, I didn't.