# pip is trying to install packages with C extensions into global directories on OSX

Tags: python, macos, pip, distribute

I have a virtualenv with Python 2.7 and I'm trying to install some packages that have C extensions (in this case, pygame and/or pyaudio):

```
$ which pip
/Users/fyhuang/env/bin/pip
$ pip -V
pip 1.4 from /Users/fyhuang/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```

When I try to install these packages, however, pip decides that it wants to install the compiled C extensions into the system directories, instead of the virtualenv:

```
running install_lib

creating /lib

error: could not create '/lib': Permission denied
```

Is this expected behavior from pip? If not, has anyone else run into this issue before? This is on OSX 10.8.

Comment: I also see this behavior on 10.9, using either the default system python 2.7.5 or homebrew python 3.3.4, whether or not I'm using virtualenv.  Would love to find a solution...

Comment: And not just with pip, but also with a straight `python setup.py install`.  It seems to be a `setuptools` issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out a workaround. I had previously seen this question/answer on SO:

[Combine --user with --prefix error with setup.py install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495120/combine-user-with-prefix-error-with-setup-py-install)

Which suggested the creation of a `~/.pydistutils.cfg` file to solve the `--user` problem. However, that file also creates incorrect behavior (as above) for installing packages with C extensions into `--user`. A better workaround is to, instead of having the `~/.pydistutils.cfg` file, call `pip` with the following arguments:

```
pip install --user --install-option="--prefix" pygame
```

That installs pygame into `--user` without messing up the C extension install directories, at least on OSX.