# Installing GEM in Python3 - The Graphic Embedding Module

Tags: python, module, installation

I am trying to install the module [GEM](https://github.com/palash1992/GEM), but the installation keeps failing with following error:

[image]

As you see, I'd cloned the repository on my local path `~/`.

[image]

The module page says as *"In case of Python 3, make sure it was compiled with ./configure --enable-shared, and that you have /usr/local/bin/python in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH"*,
but I don't know what *compiled with ./configure --enabled-shared* means and what *LD_LIBRARY_PATH* is.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine --user with --prefix error with setup.py install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495120/combine-user-with-prefix-error-with-setup-py-install)

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is an environment variable, a bit like `PATH` only used to find libraries (.so files, also known as DLLs).

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or error messages, post the text here  on SO instead.