# "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files" installing pip on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, pip, easy-install

I ran into some issues using pip on my mac, and uninstalled it altogether.

Now when I try to reinstall it, running `$sudo easy_install pip` I get:

```
TEST FAILED: /lib/python2.7/site-packages/ does NOT support .pth files
error: bad install directory or PYTHONPATH

You are attempting to install a package to a directory that is not
on PYTHONPATH and which Python does not read ".pth" files from.  The
installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /lib/python2.7/site-packages/

and your PYTHONPATH environment variable currently contains:

    ''
```

[this pasted output cut short for brevity]

I've tried adding the directory listed (/lib/python2.7/site-packages/) into my pythonpath using both ./profile and ./bash_profile, but neither affect the sys.path variable when I run python, which includes only

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC
```

Is my problem that I have two versions of python installed (under the two directories listed)?

Or is it my pythonpath is screwed up in a way that I've been unable to remedy?

---

Edit:

`$ which python` returns `/usr/bin/python`

and `$ which easy_install` returns `/usr/bin/easy_install`

Comment: Could you add the output of `which python` and `which easy_install`?

Comment: Sure, I edited it in.

Comment: OK, that didn't reveal anything. How did you uninstall `pip`? What version of macOS are you running? What version of python does it have installed?

Comment: I see that you posted a solution (delete `~/.pydistutils.cfg`) and then deleted it. Looking at sources indicates this can be the reason indeed. Did it fail in the end or something?

Comment: Wasn't sure at the time if that had done the trick, or if another problem was related. I've undeleted it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out.

When I tried to install python2 via brew, then ran `brew doctor` I got the following warning.

```
Warning: A .pydistutils.cfg file was found in $HOME, which may cause Python
builds to fail. See:
  https://bugs.python.org/issue6138
  https://bugs.python.org/issue4655
```

Sure enough, when I deleted .pydistutils.cfg the problem cleared up.

---

FWIW, here's the SO question that got me to create the file to begin with:

[Combine --user with --prefix error with setup.py install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495120/combine-user-with-prefix-error-with-setup-py-install)

(The answer there does mention it may cause unintended consequences. I just figure that linking to it may help search visibility for anyone who currently has the same problem that I had, but has forgotten that they created that file.)

Comment: That solved my issues with virtualenv. I looked everywhere for a solution for hours. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have an exact answer I can fill in some blanks for you.

Your `sys.path` doesn't show two versions of Python installed, it shows one installed according to the slightly strange way Apple installs Python 2.

The directories under `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/` are the libraries and modules for your Python. As the `/System/Library/` directories are "protected" on a Mac they can't be written to with SIP active so Apple provide the directory `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages` which is where Python packages such as `pip` are installed.

On my system `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install pip` does the install into `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`.

Since your `pip` doesn't run the next step I would suggest is see if you can get it bootstrapped from the standard library - `sudo python -m ensurepip --default-pip`. If that doesn't work you can find instructions on how to get it running [here](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#id12).