# Distutils error when installing pyperclip into Mu editor on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, distutils, mu

I'm trying to install the *pyperclip* module for the Mu editor and running into this pile of errors when I run it through the command line:

```
C:\Users\Torthew>pip install pyperclip --target C:\Users\Torthew\AppData\Local\Mu\pkgs
Collecting pyperclip
  Using cached pyperclip-1.7.0.tar.gz (15 kB)
Installing collected packages: pyperclip
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Torthew\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Torthew\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 395, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\Users\Torthew\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 67, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\Torthew\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 781, in install
    scheme = get_scheme(
  File "C:\Users\Torthew\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations.py", line 185, in get_scheme
    scheme = distutils_scheme(
  File "C:\Users\Torthew\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\locations.py", line 125, in distutils_scheme
    i.finalize_options()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 252, in finalize_options
    raise DistutilsOptionError("can't combine user with prefix, "
distutils.errors.DistutilsOptionError: can't combine user with prefix, exec_prefix/home, or install_(plat)base
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/mu-editor/mu/issues/822

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495120/combine-user-with-prefix-error-with-setup-py-install

Comment: Thank you very much for the response! Did help a ways, but kept running into issues with the command line. However! The alpha version of Mu has a 3rd party module installer built into it, so I can recommend downloading that.

Comment: You can write an answer explaining what exactly you did to solve the problem, and then mark that answer as accepted. This is better than adding "solved" to the title of the question.