# How to parse/read a YAML file into a Python object?

Tags: python, parsing, yaml

How to parse/read a YAML file into a Python object?

For example, this YAML:

```
Person:
  name: XYZ
```

To this Python class:

```
class Person(yaml.YAMLObject):
  yaml_tag = 'Person'

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
```

I am using PyYAML by the way.

Comment: I'd suggest using [`python-box`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63071957/2137370).

Comment: How can I parse a YAML file in Python?  is definitely not the same question as  How to parse/read a YAML file into a Python object?  General parsing and parsing into an object oriented structure are two different things. I am voting to reopen - and just see how many upvotes the answers here have ...

Answer (score 219, accepted):

If your YAML file looks like this:

```
# tree format
treeroot:
    branch1:
        name: Node 1
        branch1-1:
            name: Node 1-1
    branch2:
        name: Node 2
        branch2-1:
            name: Node 2-1
```

And you've installed `PyYAML` like this:

```
pip install PyYAML
```

And the Python code looks like this:

```
import yaml
with open('tree.yaml') as f:
    # use safe_load instead load
    dataMap = yaml.safe_load(f)
```

The variable `dataMap` now contains a dictionary with the tree data. If you print `dataMap` using PrettyPrint, you will get something like:

```
{
    'treeroot': {
        'branch1': {
            'branch1-1': {
                'name': 'Node 1-1'
            },
            'name': 'Node 1'
        },
        'branch2': {
            'branch2-1': {
                'name': 'Node 2-1'
            },
            'name': 'Node 2'
        }
    }
}
```

So, now we have seen how to get data into our Python program. Saving data is just as easy:

```
with open('newtree.yaml', "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(dataMap, f)
```

You have a dictionary, and now you have to convert it to a Python object:

```
class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **entries): 
        self.__dict__.update(entries)
```

Then you can use:

```
>>> args = your YAML dictionary
>>> s = Struct(**args)
>>> s
<__main__.Struct instance at 0x01D6A738>
>>> s...
```

and follow "[Convert Python dict to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object)".

For more information you can look at [pyyaml.org](http://pyyaml.org/) and [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20130809020433/http://mikkel.elmholdt.dk/?p=4).

Comment: @personal_cloud Never is a bit strong. A Python application running in a Docker container o embedded (as quick examples) might choose to not use a virtualenv when it's an extra layer that provides no isolation above and beyond what the container itself is already providing.

Comment: Assuming that `pip install PyYAML` just works is naive. Also `PyYAML`  itself is often unnecessary. See my answer.

Answer (score 19):

From http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation:

`add_path_resolver(tag, path, kind)` adds a path-based implicit tag resolver. A path is a list of keys that form a path to a node in the representation graph. Paths elements can be string values, integers, or None. The kind of a node can be str, list, dict, or None.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import yaml

class Person(yaml.YAMLObject):
  yaml_tag = '!person'

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name

yaml.add_path_resolver('!person', ['Person'], dict)

data = yaml.load("""
Person:
  name: XYZ
""")

print data
# {'Person': <__main__.Person object at 0x7f2b251ceb10>}

print data['Person'].name
# XYZ
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote an implementation using [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) that I believe is neat because of it being a bit readable. It handles the cases where your dictionary is nested as well. The parser code is as follows:

```py
from collections import namedtuple


class Dict2ObjParser:
    def __init__(self, nested_dict):
        self.nested_dict = nested_dict

    def parse(self):
        nested_dict = self.nested_dict
        if (obj_type := type(nested_dict)) is not dict:
            raise TypeError(f"Expected 'dict' but found '{obj_type}'")
        return self._transform_to_named_tuples("root", nested_dict)

    def _transform_to_named_tuples(self, tuple_name, possibly_nested_obj):
        if type(possibly_nested_obj) is dict:
            named_tuple_def = namedtuple(tuple_name, possibly_nested_obj.keys())
            transformed_value = named_tuple_def(
                *[
                    self._transform_to_named_tuples(key, value)
                    for key, value in possibly_nested_obj.items()
                ]
            )
        elif type(possibly_nested_obj) is list:
            transformed_value = [
                self._transform_to_named_tuples(f"{tuple_name}_{i}", possibly_nested_obj[i])
                for i in range(len(possibly_nested_obj))
            ]
        else:
            transformed_value = possibly_nested_obj

        return transformed_value
```

I tested basic cases with the following code:

```py
x = Dict2ObjParser({
    "a": {
        "b": 123,
        "c": "Hello, World!"
    },
    "d": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "e": [
        {
            "f": "",
            "g": None
        },
        {
            "f": "Foo",
            "g": "Bar"
        },
        {
            "h": "Hi!",
            "i": None
        }
    ],
    "j": 456,
    "k": None
}).parse()

print(x)
```

It gives the following output: `root(a=a(b=123, c='Hello, World!'), d=[1, 2, 3], e=[e_0(f='', g=None), e_1(f='Foo', g='Bar'), e_2(h='Hi!', i=None)], j=456, k=None)`

Which when formatted a bit looks like:

```
root(
    a=a(
        b=123,
        c='Hello, World!'
    ),
    d=[1, 2, 3],
    e=[
        e_0(
            f='',
            g=None
        ),
        e_1(
            f='Foo',
            g='Bar'
        ),
        e_2(
            h='Hi!',
            i=None
        )
    ],
    j=456,
    k=None
)
```

And I can access the nested fields like any other object:

```py
print(x.a.b)  # Prints: 123
```

In your case, the code would ultimately look as follows:

```py
import yaml


with open(file_path, "r") as stream:
    nested_dict = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    nested_objt = Dict2ObjParser(nested_dict).parse()
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way to test which YAML implementation the user has selected on the virtualenv (or the system) and then define `load_yaml_file` appropriately:

```
load_yaml_file = None

if not load_yaml_file:
    try:
        import yaml
        load_yaml_file = lambda fn: yaml.load(open(fn))
    except:
        pass

if not load_yaml_file:
    import commands, json
    if commands.getstatusoutput('ruby --version')[0] == 0:
        def load_yaml_file(fn):
            ruby = "puts YAML.load_file('%s').to_json" % fn
            j = commands.getstatusoutput('ruby -ryaml -rjson -e "%s"' % ruby)
            return json.loads(j[1])

if not load_yaml_file:
    import os, sys
    print """
ERROR: %s requires ruby or python-yaml  to be installed.

apt-get install ruby

  OR

apt-get install python-yaml

  OR

Demonstrate your mastery of Python by using pip.
Please research the latest pip-based install steps for python-yaml.
Usually something like this works:
   apt-get install epel-release
   apt-get install python-pip
   apt-get install libyaml-cpp-dev
   python2.7 /usr/bin/pip install pyyaml
Notes:
Non-base library (yaml) should never be installed outside a virtualenv.
"pip install" is permanent:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall
Beware when using pip within an aptitude or RPM script.
  Pip might not play by all the rules.
  Your installation may be permanent.
Ruby is 7X faster at loading large YAML files.
pip could ruin your life.
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46326059/
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36410756/
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8022240/
Never use PyYaml in numerical applications.
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458977/
If you are working for a Fortune 500 company, your choices are
1. Ask for either the "ruby" package or the "python-yaml"
package. Asking for Ruby is more likely to get a fast answer.
2. Work in a VM. I highly recommend Vagrant for setting it up.

""" % sys.argv[0]
    os._exit(4)


# test
import sys
print load_yaml_file(sys.argv[1])
```