# How to undo a Python setuptools --prefix path blunder

Tags: python, setuptools, pip

When I installed Python's [`setuptools`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) I absent mindedly tacked on a `--prefix` path I had been using on another machine:

```
sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg --prefix=/opt/python2.7.2
```

Now after this blunder when I try to install `pip` I get the following error:

```
[root@kkdev src]# easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.0.2
Processing pip-1.0.2-py2.7.egg
pip 1.0.2 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/bin
error: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

What's happening is that a symbolic link is being created that points to the folder I specified in the `--prefix` path:

```
[root@kkdev src]# ls -al /usr/bin/pip
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 24 Nov  5 17:01 /usr/bin/pip -> /opt/python2.7.2/bin/pip
```

I deleted this link and then re-ran the setuptools installer and specified the correct prefix (my Python install lives in `/usr/lib/python2.7`):

```
sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg --prefix=/usr
```

I then re-ran `easy_install pip` and it looked like I'd fixed my finger trouble. However when I went to install `virtualenv` I encountered the same problem:

```
[root@kkdev src]# pip install virtualenv

[uninteresting installer dialogue snipped]

Installing virtualenv script to /usr/bin

error: /usr/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory
```

Again the wrong path is being used to create the symbolic link to where `virtualenv` is installed:

```
[root@kkdev src]# ls -al /usr/bin/virtualenv
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31 Nov  5 17:01 /usr/bin/virtualenv -> /opt/python2.7.2/bin/virtualenv
```

(I'm running Fedora 15 32bit which has Python 2.7.1 installed out of the box)

How do I fix this permanently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get back to square one by using brute force and eradicating any and all evidence of `setuptools`, `easy_install` and `pip` from my `site-packages` folder.

After that I re-ran `sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg` **without** the `--prefix` switch and things are as they should be now.

Comment: Great answer; thank you. I've incorporated it into my answer about PyYAML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866600/

Answer (score 0):

`easy_install --help` mentions that you can specify `--prefix` there as well

I think by default this will come from `~/.pydistutils.py`

Comment: I couldn't find a `.pydistutils.py` file anywhere.