# Edit yaml file with Python

Tags: python

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127686/parsing-a-yaml-file-and-accessing-the-data) it was described how to edit specific entries of yaml files with python. I tried to use the code for the following yaml file

```
 - fields: {domain: "www.mydomain.com", name: "www.mydomain.com"}
   model: sites.site
   pk: 1
```

but with

```
with open('my.yaml', 'r') as f:
    doc = yaml.load(f)
txt = doc["fields"]["domain"]
print txt
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 9, in <module>
    txt = doc["fields"]["domain"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Now, I thought I could use keys on `doc`.. Can somebody help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you get back is a list.

Change

```
txt = doc["fields"]["domain"]
```

to

```
txt = doc[0]["fields"]["domain"]
```

Comment: You can `print type(doc)` to find out the type of data structure by the way. And if it's just simple built-ins, `print doc` is revealing enough to let you see how the data is nested.

Answer (score 1):

You can use keys, but the fact that you've started your document with `-` implies that it is a list. If you print `doc` you will see this:

```
[{'fields': {'domain': 'www.mydomain.com', 'name': 'www.mydomain.com'},
  'model': 'sites.site',
  'pk': 1}]
```

that is, a list consisting of a single element, which is itself a dict. You could access it like this:

```
txt = doc[0]["fields"]["domain"]
```

or, if you're only ever going to have a single element, remove the initial `-` (and the indents on the other lines).