# Parse yaml into a list in python

Tags: python, list, yaml, pyyaml

I am required to use YAML for a project. I have a YAML file which I am using to populate a list in a Python program which interacts with the data.

My data looks like this:

```
Employees:
    custid: 200
    user: Ash
        - Smith
        - Cox
```

I need the python code to iterate over this YAML file and populate a list like this:

```
list_of_Employees = ['Ash', 'Smith' 'Cox']
```

I know I must open the file and then store the data in a variable, but I cannot figure out how to enter each element separately in a list. Ideally I would like to use the append function so I don't have to determine my 'user' size every time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a YAML file in Python, and accessing the data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127686/parsing-a-yaml-file-in-python-and-accessing-the-data)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
with open("employees.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    out = yaml.load(stream)
    print out['Employees']['user']
```

Should already give you list of users.Also note that your yaml missing one dash after user node

Comment: Thank you, The missing dash was causing the problem

Comment: On newer versions of Python, you have to use `safe_load` instead of `load` otherwise you'll get this error: ` YAMLLoadWarning: calling yaml.load() without Loader=... is deprecated, as the default Loader is unsafe. Please read https://msg.pyyaml.org/load for full details.`

Comment: @RaleighL. or add required positional argument 'Loader', e.g. `Loader=yaml.FullLoader`

Answer (score 8):

YAML sequences are translated to python lists for you (at least when using  [PyYAML](https://bitbucket.org/xi/pyyaml) or [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml)), so you don't have to append anything yourself.

In both PyYAML and ruamel.yaml you either hand a file/stream to the `load()` routine or you hand it a string. Both:

```
import ruamel.yaml

with open('input.yaml') as fp:
    data = ruamel.yaml.load(fp)
```

and

```
import ruamel.yaml

with open('input.yaml') as fp:
    str_data = fp.read()
data = ruamel.yaml.load(str_data)
```

do the same thing.

Assuming you corrected your input to:

```
Employees:
    custid: 200
    user:
    - Ash
    - Smith
    - Cox
```

you can print out data:

```
{'Employees': {'custid': 200, 'user': ['Ash', 'Smith', 'Cox']}}
```

and see that the list is already there and can be accessed via normal dict lookups: `data['Employees']['user']`