# Import from YAML file

Tags: python, flask, yaml

I have a `config.yaml` file that I want to import in my `app.py`.

This is my folder structure:

```
 /root
      __init__.py
      app.py
      config.yaml
```

**App.py:**

```
   import logging
   import config
   from flask import Flask

   app = Flask(__name__)
   logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

   app.run(port=5001)
```

I have no problem importing other Python modules (`.py`) but when I try to import my YAML file, i get:

```
  ImportError: No module named config
```

Does anyone know why this does not work? Do I need any dependencies to be able to import a YAML file like this?

Comment: Why did you expect to be able to import a YAML file? It's not a Python module! What's in it? Have you tried searching for a Python YAML parser?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you expect to be able to import a YAML file? It isn't Python, and it isn't an extension module, and these are the only things that Python will import.

YAML (Yet Another Markup Language) is a data format, so you have to read the data with a suitable library: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-in-python) might give you some clues.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I forgot to mention that in my post. I do have that in my __init__  file. I thought that parser would make me able to import my 'config' in other .py files.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import YAML files directly into Python as you suggest in your example - only `*.py` files. You can import the `yaml` Python module and parse your file, as shown in these SO answers:

[How can I parse a YAML file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-in-python)

[Parsing a YAML file in Python, and accessing the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127686/parsing-a-yaml-file-in-python-and-accessing-the-data)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I forgot to mention that in my post. I do have that in my __init__.py file. I thought that parser would make me able to import my 'config'.

Comment: I'm afraid, that's not as works ;-) You need to manually parse the file.