# Convert several YAML files to CSV

Tags: python, csv, yaml

I am very new to Python and have several YAML files that I need to convert into csv. These are notes, comments and emails that came from our CRM (Highrise). I ONLY need the Notes and Comments, not the emails. Here are a few examples.

Test_Co_1.txt

```
---
- ID: 273679215
  Name: Test Company 1
  Tags: 
  - Sample tag 1
  - Sample tag 2
  - Sample tag 3
  - Sample tag 4
- Contact: 
  - 
    - Addresses
    - 
      - "123 W Elm Street, Anywhere, FL, 11111, United States"
  - 
    - Phone_numbers
    - 
      - 555-111-2222
- Background: sample text
- Note 424169327: 
  - 
    Author: Diane S.
  - 
    Written: "May 16, 2017 19:32"
  - 
    About: Jeff Smith
  - 
    Body: Called 5/16/17 - Receptionist indicated Jeff was unavailable. She said they are not interested in attending any webinars hung up.
- Note 424598243: 
  - 
    Author: Jenny S.
  - 
    Written: "May 18, 2017 15:45"
  - 
    About: Test Company 1
  - 
    Body: |-
      email sent to TM: Pete

      Pete,

      Can you help us with this prospective customer to determine if he is interested?

      We made some outbound calls this week, inviting dealers to the prospective dealer Summer Series webinars, with the first one being this Friday.  Can you see if Jeff is interested?  We do not have an email for him.  Do you have that?

      This is the note from earlier this week:
      Called 5/16/17 - Receptionist indicated Jeff was unavailable. She said they are not interested in attending any webinars hung up.

      Thanks for your help.
      photo

      Jenny
- Comment 424601588: 
  - 
    Author: Jenny S.
  - 
    Written: "May 18, 2017 15:56"
  - 
    About: Test Company 1
  - 
    Body: |-
      email back from TM: Jenny,

      Yes.  I will reach out to them. 

      Thanks!
      Pete
```

Another Example: Fake_Co_2

```
---
- ID: 306184746
  Name: Fake Company 2
  Tags: 
  - Sample Tag 1
- Contact: 
  - 
    - Addresses
    - 
      - "444 N Oak St, Faketon City, MI, 22222, United States"
  - 
    - Phone_numbers
    - 
      - 333-333-3333
- Note 473905168: 
  - 
    Author: Robin S.
  - 
    Written: "February 20, 2018 22:19"
  - 
    About: Fake Company 2
  - 
    Body: "1:1 with Steven 2/27/18"
- Email 476444812: 
  - 
    Author: Aaron N.
  - 
    Written: "March 06, 2018 16:30"
  - 
    About: Jose Viago
  - 
    Subject: Welcome Call
  - 
    Body: |-
      Hello Jose,



      We just talked and we scheduled your welcome call.  I noticed after we hung
      up that time changes this weekend.  Unfortunately Arizona
      doesn't change time and we will now be 2 hours behind you.  Are you
      available on at 10:30 AM CST on Tuesday, March 13th?  Otherwise I will need
      to schedule at a different time.  



      I apologize for the error and inconvenience. 




       <http://fakedomain.com/> 

      Support Team Lead 
      D: xxx-xxx-xxxx | C: xxx-xxx-xxxx | F: xxx-xxx-xxxx 
       <mailto:noreply@fakedomain.com> noreply@fakedomain.com 




       <http://fakedomain.com/> Website |
      <https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxx> Our Story


      Confidentiality Disclaimer: This email may contain confidential and/or
      private 
      information. If you received this email in error please delete and notify
      sender.
- Note 476458623: 
  - 
    Author: Jamie H.
  - 
    Written: "March 06, 2018 17:12"
  - 
    About: Fake Company 2
  - 
    Body: ""
- Note 476460268: 
  - 
    Author: Aaron N.
  - 
    Written: "March 06, 2018 17:18"
  - 
    About: Fake Company 2
  - 
    Body: |-
      Called and talked to Jose and scheduled the Welcome Call for Tuesday, March 13 at 9:30 AM.  After I hung up I realized that time changes this weekend.  I left him a voice mail and emailed to see if doing the appointment at 10:30 AM would be ok.  

      Prep for appointment: Monday, March 12 at 2:30 PM 
      Welcome Call: Tuesday, March 13 at 10:30 AM CST

      Jose emailed back and said that 10:30 is fine.  

      Michael H has been scheduled
- Comment 476460532: 
  - 
    Author: Aaron N.
  - 
    Written: "March 06, 2018 17:18"
  - 
    About: Jose Viago
  - 
    Body: |-
      From: Jose Viago [mailto:fakecompany2@gmail.com] 
      Sent: Tuesday, March 6, 2018 10:01 AM
      To: admin@fakecompany.com
      Subject: Re: Welcome Call

      Yes that is fine.  Thank you! 
      Jose Viago
      Fake Company 2
      xxx-xxx-xxxx
- Note 477585004: 
  - 
    Author: Laura H.
  - 
    Written: "March 12, 2018 23:46"
  - 
    About: Fake Company 2
  - 
    Body: |-
      Welcome call prep complete. Roadmap & workbook have been saved to their profile in BOX, and updated per their provided information. 
      03/12/18 (LH)
- Note 477740716: 
  - 
    Author: Michael H.
  - 
    Written: "March 13, 2018 16:47"
  - 
    About: Fake Company 2
  - 
    Body: |-
      03-13-2018. Did a welcome call with Jose. Jose now has access to the box. We will have a follow up call for Dashboard roll out.

      03-13-2018. Did a follow up with Jose. He now has owner and tech role to the App and Dashboard. We also reviewed Online portal and help center. (MH)
- Note 502997603: 
  - 
    Author: Laura H.
  - 
    Written: "August 06, 2018 17:14"
  - 
    About: Fake Company 2
  - 
    Body: |-
      Received a text from Jose letting me know there is a leak in his office, and he needs to reschedule our call today. I moved him to Thursday 08/09/18 @ 9:00AM CDT. 
      08/06/18 (LH)
```

Some of these text files are 1000's of lines long, containing every internal note, comment, and email ever recorded for that specific customer (or contact that works for that customer).

We are moving to a different CRM and need to import the Notes and Comments only. I would like to generate a csv (or multiple csv files if needed) like this:

output.csv

```
Name,Author,Written,About,Body
"Fake Company 2"|"Robin S."|"February 20, 2018 22:19"|"Fake Company 2"|"1:1 with Steve 2/27/18"
"Fake Company 2"|"Aaron N."|"March 06, 2018 17:18"|"Fake Company 2"|"Called and talked to Jose and scheduled the Welcome Call for Tuesday, March 13 at 9:30 AM.  After I hung up I realized that time changes this weekend.  I left him a voice mail and emailed to see if doing the appointment at 10:30 AM would be ok.  

      Prep for appointment: Monday, March 12 at 2:30 PM 
      Welcome Call: Tuesday, March 13 at 10:30 AM CST

      Jose emailed back and said that 10:30 is fine.  

      Michael H has been scheduled"
```

I found this code [Need a script that extracts from a yaml file content and output as a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46679787/need-a-script-that-extracts-from-a-yaml-file-content-and-output-as-a-csv-file#) but I do not know enough about Python to get it to work without syntax errors.

Comment: What part are you struggling with? What were your attempts with the syntax errors?

Comment: (and what are the syntax errors?)

Comment: That looks like one big file with multiple YAML documents at the second of which is invalid YAML (combining a list and multi-line plain scalar at the root level). You are not going to be able to parse that with a YAML parser. (If that is not a single file with multiple YAML documents, then make an effort in formatting and don't present it as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make use of a Python YAML library to help with doing that. This could be installed using:

```
pip install pyyaml
```

The files you have given could then be converted to CSV as follows:

```
import csv
import yaml

fieldnames = ['Name', 'Author', 'Written', 'About', 'Body']

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_output.writeheader()

    for filename in ['Test_Co_1.txt', 'Test_Co_2.txt']:
        with open(filename) as f_input:
            data = yaml.safe_load(f_input)

        name = data[0]['Name']

        for entry in data:
            key = next(iter(entry))

            if key.startswith('Note') or key.startswith('Comment'):
                row = {'Name' : name}

                for d in entry[key]:
                    for get in ['Author', 'Written', 'About', 'Body']:
                        try:
                            row[get] = d[get]
                        except KeyError as e:
                            pass

                csv_output.writerow(row)
```

This assumes a standard CSV format (i.e. commas between fields and quotes are used if a field contains a newline or commas).

To understand this, I would recommend you add some print statements to see what things look like. For example `data` holds then entire file contents in a format of lists and dictionaries. It is then a case of extracting the bits you need.

To apply this to all of your YAML files, I would replacing the filenames with a call to `glob.glob('*.txt')`

Comment: Thank you Martin. This was extremely helpful. This correctly converts most of my files to a csv however I do get some errors on some with special characters. I'm positive it is an encoding issue but have not cleared it up just yet. Thanks again for your time and helping someone that is very new to python.

Comment: You could try opening the files with `with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as f_input:`