# Import YAML variables automatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, pyyaml

I've provided the code below. I'm just wondering if there's a better, more concise, way to load the entire index into variables, instead of manually specifying each one...

**Python code**

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, 'config.yaml')

with open(file_path, 'r') as stream:
    index = 'two'
    load = yaml.load(stream)
    USER = load[index]['USER']
    PASS = load[index]['PASS']
    HOST = load[index]['HOST']
    PORT = load[index]['PORT']
    ...
```

**YAML Config**

```
one:
  USER: "john"
  PASS: "qwerty"
  HOST: "127.0.0.1"
  PORT: "20"
two:
  USER: "jane"
  PASS: "qwerty"
  HOST: "196.162.0.1"
  PORT: "80"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing a YAML file in Python, and accessing the data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127686/parsing-a-yaml-file-in-python-and-accessing-the-data)

Comment: Try using https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation

Comment: This provides an example of how I currently set up my code. In other words, I want the program to import all variables automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assing to `globals()`:

```
import yaml
import os

script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, 'config.yaml')

index = 'two'

with open(file_path, 'r') as stream:
    load = yaml.safe_load(stream)

for key in load[index]:
    globals()[str(key)] = load[index][key]

print(USER)
print(PORT)
```

this gives:

```
jane
80
```

A few notes:

- Using global variables is often considered bad practise
- As noted by `a p` in the comment, this can lead to problems e.g. with keys that shadow built-ins
- If you have to use PyYAML, you should use `safe_load()`.
- You should consider using `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that package), where you can get the same result with:

  ```
  import ruamel.yaml
  yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
  ```

  and then again use `load = yaml.load(stream)` (which is safe).

Comment: Note that this is potentially problematic since it will shadow builtins and things like True and False.

Comment: Your answer was helpful! I'll check out your package as well. Thank you for responding : )