# How can I get rid of this warning to upgrade from pip?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Whenever I use pip, it warns me that my pip is out of date and that I need to upgrade it by doing `pip install --upgrade pip`.

But when I do that it seemingly has no effect and simply tells me the same thing. It's circular!

How can I fix this? See below

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in my-virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

***EDIT:*** I'm running Red Hat Enterprise Linux (on AWS). So I just tried uninstalling and reinstalling python-pip. When I did that it tells me it will install pip 6.1.1.-1.21.amzn1. How can I make it install the newer version??

Comment: Did you try `--quiet` ? Or `pip install --upgrade pip==8.1.1` ?

Comment: If you have python 2 and 3 installed on your computer make sure you're upgrading the correct version of pip. Use `pip2` or just `pip` for python 2 and `pip3` for python 3.

Comment: Haha `--quiet` suppresses everything *except* the obnoxious warning. Gotta love `pip`.

Comment: The warning might as well say `Version 6.0.8 used to work on your system, in fact RH shipped with it. But pip likes to go out and break itself from time to time.`

Answer (score 3):

This one was resolved here:

[How to suppress pip upgrade warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288847/how-to-install-pip-correctly/46288945#46288945)

There is a known issue with `pip` where it will print that warning even if you have the version of pip that shipped with your OS. It is safe to get rid of the warning with this command:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.config/pip
printf "[global]\ndisable-pip-version-check = True\n" \
  > $HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf
```

Comment: Probably better to do `pip config set global.disable-pip-version-check True` so you don't have to mess around with file paths.

Comment: This comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

twice.

The first time it upgrades to version `8.1.0` and the second time to `8.1.1`. After this there will be no warnings anymore.

Comment: That didn't work. It stays the same no matter how many times I run it.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question about how to suppress the warning.

Comment: Thanks. Twice running `pip install --upgrade pip` solved warning  `You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 9.0.1 is available.  You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

Answer (score 0):

You can install pip using system package manager,

for ubuntu/debian:
`apt-get install python-pip`

for arch:
`pacman -S python-pip`

In this the package manager will update pip every time a new version will be available for your distribution.

Comment: Off topic. Doesn't answer the question about how to suppress the warning.

Comment: Also, on CentOS 7.3 at least, you will need to `yum install epel-release` first.