# Recommended way to install pip(3) on centos7

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6, centos7

I am interrested in knowing the recommended way to install pip3 for python3.6 (as of today, may 2018) on current version of centos7 (7.5.1804) and the accepted answer of [How to install pip in CentOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618686/how-to-install-pip-in-centos-7) seems to be outdated because:

```
yum search -v pip
```

outputs (among other things):

```
python2-pip.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python 2 packages
Repo        : epel

python34-pip.noarch : A tool for installing and managing Python3 packages
Repo        : epel
```

and `python34-pip` seems to be a (newer?) simpler way than the accepted answer of [How to install pip in CentOS 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618686/how-to-install-pip-in-centos-7) :

> sudo yum install python34-setuptools
>
> sudo easy_install-3.4 pip

But since the versions of python installed on my machine are 2.7.5 and 3.6.3 why is it python34-pip and not python36-pip ? Is pip the same for 3.4+ (up to current 3.6.3) ?

Comment: See also: [EPEL Python 3.6 with pip on CentOS 7](https://cjsawer.whitewillow.co.uk/2018/08/29/epel-python-3-6-with-pip-on-centos-7/)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. > Is pip the same for 3.4+

   No, it's not. A single `pip` installation serves a single Python distribution (`pip2.7`/`pip3.4`/`pip3.5` etc).
2. Since Python 3.5, `pip` is already bundled with the python distribution, so you can just run `python3.6 -m pip` instead of `pip`.
3. Python 3.6 is not available in CentOS 7 vanilla repo. I usually resort to [IUS repo](https://ius.io) when needing to install a fresh Python on CentOS. It always has the most recent Python version, [the current one being 3.6.5](https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/7/SRPMS/repoview/python36u.html). It also offers a correspondent [`pip` package](https://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/7/SRPMS/repoview/python36u-pip.html).

   ```
   $ yum install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
   $ yum install python36u python36u-devel python36u-pip
   ```

   Unfortunately, IUS [doesn't offer a package for Python 3.7 yet](https://github.com/iuscommunity/wishlist/issues/200) so if you are looking for Python 3.7 on CentOS 7, building from source is your only option.

#### Edit: when `yum` is not an option

You should prefer the bootstrapping solution described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52518512/2650249) as it is the most reliable way to get a working `pip` installed.

Comment: Didn't know that since python 3.5 pip is bundled, this solves my question, not sure why I was downvoted but thanks.

Comment: Probably because it would better fit in [superuser](https://superuser.com) or [serverfault](https://serverfault)? Nevertheless, not enough for me to downvote; upvoted.

Comment: Pip did not come bundled in the EPEL version of python36 on my CentOS7 machine, just an FYI. I had to use the setuptools package to get it.

Comment: @xjsc16x yeah well it is available in the IUS repo; this is why I added this answer in first place.

Comment: The rpm repo has been moved to https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm

Answer (score 45):

To install pip for python 3.6 on CentOS 7 you need to run

`$ python3.6 -m ensurepip`

Comment: This one is the most up to date solution and should be preferred if `pip` is not installable via `yum`.

Comment: See [EPEL Python 3.6 with pip on CentOS 7](https://cjsawer.whitewillow.co.uk/2018/08/29/epel-python-3-6-with-pip-on-centos-7/) for a more complete answer about how to install `python3.6` via EPEL.

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: I just used this trick to drastically simplify some Ansible playbooks (via the shell and command modules); Ansible could use my specified python3 interpreter but couldn't find its pip. This made it work, and reduced the number of tasks I needed

Comment: It need to do an upgrade on pip3 to work correctly for me:
```pip3 install --upgrade pip```

Answer (score 26):

Follow these commands in Centos 7

```
yum install python36
yum install python36-devel
yum install python36-setuptools
easy_install-3.6 pip
```

to check the pip version:

```
pip3 -V
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-18.0-py3.6.egg/pip (python 3.6)
```

Answer (score 17):

There is now a `python3-pip` package in the CentOS 7 [base repository](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/) as of 2019-08-22. *There is no longer a need for third-party repositories or packages.*

Installing `python3-pip` will also install `libtirpc`, `python3`, `python3-libs`, and `python3-setuptools`:

```
yum install --assumeyes python3-pip
```

You can now verify the version (yes, [it is old](https://pypi.org/project/pip/#history), but it's what is coming from the base repository):

```
$ pip3 --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

If you don't want to stray from the files provided by the `python3-pip` package, and you don't want to see warnings about pip being old, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46288945/534275 for silencing the messages.

Comment: Thanks! this is the only instruction worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Pip is not bundled in the EPEL version of python 3.6 for some reason. I assume a decent amount of people (such as me) will find this page because of that.

```
$ sudo yum install -y python36
...
$ python36 -m pip
/usr/bin/python36: No module named pip
```

So in this case, the setuptools package was the easiest solution.

```
$ sudo yum install python36-setuptools
$ sudo easy_install-3.6 pip
...
$ python36 -m pip --version
pip 18.0 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip-18.0-py3.6.egg/pip (python 3.6)
```

Answer (score 4):

In case you're seeing that pip3 is linked to python2 path:

> $ pip3 -V
>
> pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)

You'll probably get:

> $ pip3 install --upgrade pip
>
> TypeError: parse() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transport_encoding'

Then try to clear commands cache with ***hash -r***. This has worked for me:

```
# Install Python 3:
sudo yum install python36 -y

# Install & Upgrade pip3
sudo python36 -m pip install --upgrade pip

# Validate pip3 installation:
sudo python3.6 -m ensurepip
#  Successfully installed pip-10.0.1 setuptools-39.0.1

# Clear commands cache
hash -r
# might be required if getting in bash: /usr/bin/pip3: No such file or directory)

pip3 -V
# pip 19.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

which pip3
# /usr/local/bin/pip3

pip2 -V
# pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)

which pip2
# /usr/local/bin/pip2

# Install your Python3 module:
sudo /usr/local/bin/pip3 install {required module for python3}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this error when I tried to install python36 over the built-in centos7 python 2.7.5 version:

```
Transaction check error:
  file /etc/rpm/macros.python from install of python-rpm-macros-3-32.el7.noarch conflicts with file from package python-devel-2.7.5-80.el7_6.x86_64
```

And I fixed it with these:

```
yum install python36
yum update python-devel
yum install python36-devel
easy_install-3.6 pip
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This::

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip
```

Working for me perfectly.