# Need to invoke pip with pip36 command

Tags: python, linux, pip

Let me elaborate my problem clearly.

We installed `python3.6` recently as below in one of our linux VM

```
yum install python36
```

entering `python36` will invoke `python3.6` interpreter. Now we want to install pip for this, we tried as below

```
python36 -m ensure-pip --default-pip
```

which resulted in invoking pip with pip command in a path (`/usr/bin/pip`) that comes before the 2.7 version's pip in the same machine (Env path) due to which we are explicitly calling 2.7's pip with path as `/bin/pip`

But we wanted to invoke pip as pip36 command, so the solution we wanted which should help us like, whenever we hit pip it should invoke 2.7's and whenever we invoke pip36 it should invoke 3.6's

NOTE: we do not want to change the PATH variable for this

Comment: Can you call python36 in the prompt ?

Comment: can you share the output of the command - "whereis pip" ?

Comment: `python36 -m pip` will run the pip which is in `python36`, not some other one. But `python36` may actually be something else than what the name says

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to install pip(3) on centos7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408941/recommended-way-to-install-pip3-on-centos7)

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](https://janikarhunen.fi/how-to-install-python-3-6-1-on-centos-7.html) manual.

Line below should do the work:

```
sudo yum install python36u-pip
```