# How to install pip specifically for Python3 on CentOS 7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, centos7, python-2.x

CentOS 7 already has Python2.7.5 stock installed. I am doing an online course that requires Python3.x installed. So these are the following steps i took to install Python3.7.3.rc1 :

```
$cd /usr/src
$sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.3/Python-3.7.3rc1.tgz
$sudo tar xzf Python-3.7.3rc1.tgz
$cd Python-3.7.3rc1
$sudo ./configure --enable-optimizations
$sudo make altinstall
$sudo rm /usr/src/Python-3.7.3rc1.tgz
$python3.7 --version
Python 3.7.3rc1
```

I followed these steps religiously from this link : https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-centos/

During my course i was required to install pyperclip using pip.
So i did :

```
$python3.7 -m pip install pyperclip
/usr/local/bin/python3.7: No module named pip
```

Please suggest a method to install pip for Python3.7.3rc1.

Comment: Have you tried running the `pip` command directly, without `python` before it? Like: `pip install pyperclip`.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that running pip directly uses Python2.7.5. So importing pyperclip in Python3.7.3rc1 gives error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'` but works fine for Python2.7.5.

Comment: I see. How about running `pip3`? Does it show something to you?

Comment: No, `bash: pip3: command not found...`.

Comment: Think you've done a lot of work for a beginner unnecessarily. Try installing the python36 package that's the default supported python3.x series in centos 7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to install pip(3) on centos7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408941/recommended-way-to-install-pip3-on-centos7)

Comment: Notes for building python 3.7: it requires a recent version of OpenSSL that is not (and most probably will never be) available in CentOS 7. You would need to build OpenSSL and install it alongside the default one and then link python against it. Not something I'd recommend as there will be a lot of inconsistencies in the thrid-party python packages anyway (e.g. you'll need to build `cryptography` or `pyopenssl` from source with correct linking which is pretty much a PITA and the errors will be hard to trace).

Comment: @hoefling Your comment suggests that OpenSSL is a requirement to build Python3.7.x and is certainly not preinstalled in CentOS7. However i was still able to build the Python3.7.3rc1 package without any problem and the IDLE was working fine as then. Later it became clear to me later that pip does not get sideloaded when i install the package manually. However importing the module worked just as fine if i copied the site-packages from another Python3.7.x machine with pip running manually to my current machine. But this just created a lot of extra steps for a simple task unnecessarily.

Comment: Yepp, just checked again, CentOS 7 includes OpenSSL 1.0.2k since Nov 18, so it's not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should have taken the default available python3, that is the python3.6 package in centos7
that would have been easier to setup rather than compile an unsupported version.
Suggest you install the supported python3 package in centos

**Try doing yum install python36 from repository**

```
sudo yum install -y https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm
```

**Update yum package**

```
 sudo yum update
```

**Install python36 along with pip**

```
sudo yum install -y python36u python36u-libs python36u-devel python36u-pip
```

**Below steps are for python3.7**,
suggest avoiding unsupported packages.
Alternate Steps for pip setup for Centos
You need to install pip for python3.7 series
Step 1: First install the EPEL Repository

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

Step 2: Installing pip

```
python37 -m pip
```

Step 3: Verify if pip was installed properly
pip --version

If the command not found error shows up, try

```
python37 -m ensurepip
```

Comment: I don't think that the Step 2 installs pip but instead calls out pip. Nevertheless i did 
 it and it gives the same error `/usr/local/bin/python3.7: No module named pip
`.

Comment: Avoid python3.7 and go for python3.6 that comes with centos7. You are doing the task which tends to be difficult even for experienced programmers.

Comment: Thanks. Installing Python3.6 worked liked a charm with pip.

Comment: Also sometimes python devel issue comes where we have to run ```yum install python-devel``` before running the above commands.

Comment: For CentOS 6 Use : `yum install https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el6.rpm https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm`

Comment: Sidenote : Url changed from `https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm` to `https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm`

Answer (score 0):

I also as you said "followed these steps religiously from this link: https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-centos/."

It was not an option for me to install python3.6, as I explicitly needed 3.7.
I was able to install using the following procedure:

```
# AFAIK, libffi-devel solved the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'" I had when I tried installing without it. 
yum install libffi-devel 

cd /usr/src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.5/Python-3.7.5.tgz
tar xzf Python-3.7.5.tgz
cd Python-3.7.5
./configure --enable-optimizations
make install  # Or: make altinstall
python3 -V
pip3 --version
rm -f /usr/src/Python-3.7.5.tgz
```

What I changed from the referenced article is the version (3.7.5 instead of 3.7.4) and in addition installed "libffi-devel". It could be that this one would have solved on 3.7.4 as well.

Answer (score -1):

For CentOS 6 and 7 you can run this:

`sudo yum install python37-setuptools
sudo easy_install-3.7 pip`

Edit: You should then be able to install using `pip3 install <package>`