# How can I install pip when there is already python but pip is missed?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, centos7

I'm using a remote server, which some others use together.

There are several versions of python installed.

I need python 3.6 version, and I can run it with  `/bin/python3.6` command.

And I also want to make a virtualenv of the version, so I tried `/bin/python3.6 -m pip --version`

But it showed

```
/bin/python3.6: No module named pip
```

When I checked the lib directory, `ll /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/`

```
total 0 drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 6 Dec 20  2017 __pycache__
```

It seems that the server has python3.6, but misses pip for that, right?

How can I resolve this, with the minimum modification?

The server is centos7.

Any thought or comment appreciated :)

Comment: Can you try using `pip3` instead?

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: @Varun Running `pip3` is practically the same as `python3 -m pip`, so I doubt that's going to work.

Comment: Any chance you could use conda (miniconda) there? You will have much more control over package management right out of the box.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of [Recommended way to install pip(3) on centos7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50408941/4518341). I don't use Cent OS so idk.

Comment: @VarunNayak @wjandrea `pip3 --version` shows `command not found`

Answer (score 0):

As drum mentioned at the comment, I installed pip referring to pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing.

I ran the python file with `/usr/bin/python3.6 get-pip.py`.

After installing virtualenv, I faced `virtualenv not found` error.

You can solve the above error with the following link.(It was a path issue) [Virtualenv Command Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31133050/virtualenv-command-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to modify the system Python you can just use the zipapp version of virtualenv to create a virtual environment at some arbitrary location with latest pip included (see https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/installation.html#via-zipapp).

```sh
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/virtualenv/virtualenv.pyz
python3.6 /full/path/to/downloaded/virtualenv.pyz ~/virtualenv

~/virtualenv/bin/python -m pip list
```

That's probably the minimum harmful modification, and ensure that messing with the system python does not break your system python applications/environment.