# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip' on CentOS

Tags: pip

While running pip3.7, I am getting error as below. Vut pip module is installed.

```sh
[root@ tmp]# pip3.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3.7", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

[root@ tmp]# pip3.7 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3.7", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'

[root@tmp]# pip --version
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

[root@tmp]# pip3 --version
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

[root@tmp]# which pip3.7
/usr/local/bin/pip3.7

[root@tmp]# which python3.7
/usr/local/bin/python3.7

[root@tmp]# python3.7 
Python 3.7.7 (default, Jun 27 2020, 01:38:33) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408941/recommended-way-to-install-pip3-on-centos7/50410256

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommended way to install pip(3) on centos7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50408941/recommended-way-to-install-pip3-on-centos7)