# pip version in Pycharm2018

Tags: python, pip, ide, pycharm, opencv

I am having hard time to install and add "cv2" module in PyCharm2018, to my project.

When I run pip install cv2, I am notified that my pip version is 10.0.1. I have check forum how to upgrade it, which i did. But I am still prompted by same message, that my pip is version 10.0.1

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlbLv.png)

Project settings are showing 18.1, and python -m pip install pip confirms same, that version is 18.1. I have restarted IDE and also computer, same story.

[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpNXK.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your `pip`, the problem is `cv2`, the package name is different, try this:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

So now go ahead you can `import cv2`.

and about that warning, you can turn it off using [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46288847/how-to-suppress-pip-upgrade-warning/46288945#46288945)

Comment: Thank you so much. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Try using on terminal:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

For Python 3.6:

```
python -m pip install opencv-python
```