# How to upgrade pip in a dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, pip

In a Dockerfile where we build an image for our python projects , we have a line like this to upgrade pip to latest version:

```
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
```

This has been working well for a while, but recently the image build started to fail because we are using python 3.6.1 and latest version of pip (21.1) now requires python >= 3.6.2, otherwise you get an "ImportError: cannot import name NoReturn", see https://github.com/psf/black/issues/1666

Besides upgrading our Python version to fix this issue, I was wondering if we really should be running this command to upgrade latest version in a Dockerfile context, because when doing this we don't get a reproducible image anymore, since the pip version will continue to move, and this goes against Docker concept of reproducible environments.

So, should we specify the exact pip version to keep a reproducible build, even if that means that at some point it will be outdated? Or is there another option to ensure that our image will continue to work when a new pip version is released?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noticed, upgrading pip to the latest revision on each build of your Docker image doesn't guarantee a reproduciple build in the future. That is not a good idea.

The strategy to adopt depends on your needs. But you may consider the default pip version released with a specific Python version is a reasonable one. But to choose that, you may ensure your major Python release (3.6) is enough up-to-date. This is not your case here, since 3.6.1 is a very old release. The latest 3.6 is 3.6.13 and has been released 2 months ago (3.6 is still supported)

From https://www.python.org/downloads/

- Python 3.6.13: Feb. 15, 2021
- Python 3.6.2: July 17, 2017
- Python 3.6.1: March 21, 2017

The reason behind updating pip on docker build is often the warning displayed by Pip when it is not the latest release

```
You are using pip version 6.0.8, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

This warning is useful when you have pip on your system, it has less value inside a built docker image. There is multiple way to disable this message, see [How to suppress pip upgrade warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46288847/1887976):

CLI option

```
pip --disable-pip-version-check [normal stuff here]
```

Environment variable

```
export PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1
```

Pip config

```
pip config set global.disable-pip-version-check true
```

Pip config file (in $HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf)

```
[global]
disable-pip-version-check = True
```

Comment: thanks for the details! Indeed we will stick with the latest know pip version to work with 3.6, and plan an upgrade