# Reading YAML config to Python Script as a Variable

Tags: python

```yaml
elasticsearch-configuration:
  url: localhost
  port: 9200
  user: elastic
  password: password
correlation:
  correlations:
    name: my-custom-name
    period: 5m
    id:
      - 550
      - 551
      - 552
      - 887
    name: my-custom-name2
    period: 1m
    id:
      - 6550
      - 7551
      - 8552
```

How can I read the yaml config file from python, and run the python with each variable (name,period id)? For each correlation, I want to get the variables set in python.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
      
      name = "my-custom-name"
      period = 5m
      id = ["550", "551", "552", "887"]  

        if alert_id == id:
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse/read a YAML file into a Python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866600/how-to-parse-read-a-yaml-file-into-a-python-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pyyaml`](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/) package makes this very easy, and simply reads it as a dict:

```py
import yaml

def read_config(path):
    with open(path, "r") as stream:
        return yaml.FullLoader(stream).get_data()

cfg = read_config("path/to/it.yaml")
url = cfg['elasticsearch-configuration']['url']
```

Comment: How about setting this correlation fields as a variable on python?

Comment: You would access them the same way... `cfg['correlation']['correlations']['name']`

Comment: I want to use config file with for-loop

Comment: I've given you all you need to be able to do that. I can't write your whole script for you.