# Easiest way to fill in jinja template

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a jinja templates (python files) with several variables like this `{{ some_variable }}`. Then I have a `yml` files with the defined variable values.

python/jinja template:

```py
import datetime

some_variable = '{{ some_variable }}'
```

yaml file:

```yaml
some_variable: 'some value'
```

desired output:

```py
import datetime

some_variable = 'some value'
```

What is the fastest/easiest way to fill the templates with the `yml` variable values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse/read a YAML file into a Python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6866600/how-to-parse-read-a-yaml-file-into-a-python-object)

Comment: No, not really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, ended up with:

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import click
import yaml

def main(template_file: str, variables_file: str) -> None:
    with open(variables_file) as fin:
        variables = yaml.load(fin, Loader = yaml.SafeLoader)

    env = Environment(loader = FileSystemLoader('./'))
    template = env.get_template(template_file)

    print(template.render(**variables))
```