# Uninstall Django on Mac OS X

Tags: django, macos, uninstallation

I installed Django by downloading the tarball, then

```
$ tar xzvf Django-1.3.1.tar.gz
$ cd Django-1.3.1
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

How do I uninstall Django? I can start by deleting the folder

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.frameworks/Versions/Current/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django
```

Which other files, folders, and symlinks should I delete?

Comment: This should work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you installed Django using setup.py install, uninstalling is as simple as deleting the django directory from your Python site-packages. That is the best and only way to do it.

Reference Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/?from=olddocs

Comment: To find the directory you need to remove, you can run the following at your shell prompt (not the interactive Python prompt):
`python -c "import sys; sys.path = sys.path[1:]; import django; print(django.__path__)"`