# How to uninstall pip packages which are installed from a *.txt file?

Tags: python, django, eclipse, pip

I have just installed a bunch of pip packages and now nothing works anymore.

with:

```
pip install PATH/*.txt
```

Therefore how to uninstall my packages?

PS.: I am running win7

Comment: `pip uninstall` will uninstall individual packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some good suggestions in this related thread: [python setup.py uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall)

EDIT: Maybe you need to remove all files manually, and also undo any other stuff that installation did manually.

If you don't know the list of all files, you can reinstall it with the --record option, and take a look at the list this produces.

Comment: is there also a way to unistall everything with pip, because I installed packages from a *.txt file?

Comment: yep I have tried but i get: Cannot uninstall requirement project.txt, not installed BUT I have installed them...