# pydot and graphviz error: Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible

Tags: python, python-2.7, graphviz, pydot

When I run a very simple code with pydot

```
import pydot
graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='graph')

for i in range(3):

  edge = pydot.Edge("king", "lord%d" % i)
  graph.add_edge(edge)

vassal_num = 0
for i in range(3):
  for j in range(2):
    edge = pydot.Edge("lord%d" % i, "vassal%d" % vassal_num)
    graph.add_edge(edge)
    vassal_num += 1

graph.write_png('example1_graph.png')
```

It prints me the error message:

```
Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible.
```

I'm using python 2.7.3

Comment: `pip install pydot2` should fix this issue. Much nicer than using `pip uninstall` because if you share code you can just add pydot2 to your requirements.txt and not have users run unfamiliar commands.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

Answer for `pydot >= 1.1`:

The incompatibility of (upstream) `pydot` has been fixed by [6dff94b3f1](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/commit/6dff94b3f1dbcf68e5a83ce17a36b098c06d7c6b), and thus `pydot >= 1.1` will be [compatible with `pyparsing >= 1.5.7`](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/commit/e26af21426fcf15955f7b11b348b14dc6bd5178c).

---

Answer applicable to `pydot <= 1.0.28`:

For anyone else who comes across this, it is due to the changes in pyparsing from 1.x to the 2.x release.
To install pydot using pip, first install the older version of pyparsing:

```
pip install pyparsing==1.5.7
pip install pydot==1.0.28
```

If you did not install `pyparsing` using `pip`, but instead used `setup.py`, then have a look at this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall) to uninstall the package. Thanks @qtips.

Comment: I installed NetworkX, GraphViz and pydot, but could not get Graphviz functionality to work with NetworkX (e.g. [this](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/examples/drawing/circular_tree.html) NetworkX example failed). I kept getting: **global name 'dot_parser' is not defined**. Your solution solved this problem.

Comment: also, `sudo pip uninstall` does not work if you have installed your package using `python setup.py install` in that case, follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1550226/python-setup-py-uninstall) solution. This was at least the case on my Mountain Lion OSX Mac

Comment: `sudo` is obviously not always necessary, like if you're using a virtualenv. Other than that, this worked for me!

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04 I get this error, when installing byparsing: "Requested pyparsing==1.5.7, but installing version 2.0.1". Then the error above occurs still

So the solution was to specify the download location of the python egg:

      sudo pip install -Iv https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyparsing/pyparsing-1.5.7.tar.gz#md5=9be0fcdcc595199c646ab317c1d9a709

Comment: Minor correction for folks who uninstalled pydot before re-installing pyparsing and then re-installing pydot) "sudo pip install Graphviz" before "sudo pip install pydot" . Since pydot needs BOTH Graphviz & pyparsing" - post this I did not get the "Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible" error

Comment: This didn't work for me. The solution by Dana The Sane did. In addition it doesn't requires to downgrade your versions.

Comment: Why not just `pip install pyparsing==1.5.7`?

Comment: This also works for ``NameError: global name 'dot_parser' is not defined``

Comment: @Sadik's answer should also be mentioned here. For some reason pip install does not update path correctly on Ubuntu 14.04. `sudo apt-get install python-pydot`

Comment: For me on pydot 1.0.29, I needed to install pyparsing==2.0.6, as suggested by [this tangentially-related issue](https://github.com/stevearc/dql/issues/4). :-/

Answer (score 57):

There is a new package in the pip repo called pydot2 that functions correctly with pyparsing2. I couldn't downgrade my packages because matplotlib depends on the newer pyparsing package.

Note: python2.7 from macports

Comment: IMHO This answer should be considered over the pyparsing downgrading Idea. Works for me perfectly with networkx too. Thanks !

Comment: Still giving this error but dot_parser error gone. You must install pydot for `pydotprint` to work.

Answer (score 20):

pydot used a private module variable (_noncomma) from pyparsing. The below diff fixes it to use for pyparsing 2.0.1:

```
diff --git a/dot_parser.py b/dot_parser.py
index dedd61a..138d152 100644
--- a/dot_parser.py
+++ b/dot_parser.py
@@ -25,8 +25,9 @@ from pyparsing import __version__ as pyparsing_version
 from pyparsing import ( nestedExpr, Literal, CaselessLiteral, Word, Upcase, OneOrMore, ZeroOrMore,
     Forward, NotAny, delimitedList, oneOf, Group, Optional, Combine, alphas, nums,
     restOfLine, cStyleComment, nums, alphanums, printables, empty, quotedString,
-    ParseException, ParseResults, CharsNotIn, _noncomma, dblQuotedString, QuotedString, ParserElement )
+    ParseException, ParseResults, CharsNotIn, dblQuotedString, QuotedString, ParserElement )

+_noncomma = "".join( [ c for c in printables if c != "," ] )

 class P_AttrList:
```

Comment: Just for completeness, [here's the issue report](http://code.google.com/p/pydot/issues/detail?id=81#c9) for pydot which reports this issue and the fix mentioned by @Gabi Davar.

Answer (score 7):

I forked the pydot repository [1], applied the Gabi Davar patch and some changes to support python-3. The package is available in the PyPI [2].

Cheers

- [1] https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot2/1.0.32
- [2] https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot2

Comment: The PyPI page appears to be down. That's too bad! Any ideas why?

Comment: the pip package seems to be broken. `pip install...` failed in the middle without explicit error.  Looks like the manifest and the actual files don't match.   I checkout the git repo, and `mv README.rst README` then `python setup.py install`.  This worked for me :-)

Comment: the link, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot2, is broken but `pip install pydot2` works and this link, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot2/1.0.32, works.

Answer (score 6):

`$ sudo pip uninstall pydot`

`$ sudo pip install pydot2`

See the following link: http://infidea.net/troubleshooting-couldnt-import-dot_parser-loading-of-dot-files-will-not-be-possible/

Comment: I did vice versa ```pip uninstall pydot2``` and then ```pip install pydot``` to fix the error. Here is the link on the correct answer: https://github.com/pydot/pydot/issues/166#issuecomment-356066120

Answer (score 5):

The solution was not to install pydot from somewhere, but "python-pydot" from official ubuntu repositories.

Comment: As of 25-Aug-2013 `pip install python-pydot` does not work for me (distribution not found); `pip install pydot` does. So I don't think it's that `pydot` is necessarily unofficial. Perhaps you were installing via an OS distribution instead?

Comment: Not with pip, `sudo apt-get install python-pydot` did it for me.

Comment: That would probably work because Ubuntu currently has `python-pyparsing` at 1.5.2, which avoids the version incompatibility listed above. I went with the fix above and haven't had problems since. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately in Ubuntu as of Saucy pyparsing has been upgraded but pydot has not been patched appropriately.

Comment: I've filed a ticket to fix the Ubuntu package: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pydot/+bug/1321135

Comment: i was getting "GraphViz's executables not found" error and tried various things (try to set path for grarphviz, uninstall / install pyparser, pydot) but on my Ubuntu precise this is the only thing worked for me `sudo apt-get install python-pydot` thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There are now at least 2 more versions that appear to support PyParsing-2 and Python-3:

- [PyDotPlus](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydotplus) by [Carlos Jenkins](https://github.com/carlos-jenkins/pydotplus) with a nice travis buildbot and fancy [documentation](http://pydotplus.readthedocs.org/). However you will need to change its folder name from `site-packages\pydotplus` to `site-packages\pydot` for it to work with existing programs that import pydot.
- [pydot3k](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot3k) by [bmcorser](https://bitbucket.org/bmcorser/pydot3k/overview). **Sadly, did not work!**
- [prologic/pydot](https://bitbucket.org/prologic/pydot) by James Mills linked to from the official pydot Google code page as ...

> a branch for Python 3 compatibility
>
> and here is a working link to David Villa's pydot2 which works fine:
>   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydot2/1.0.32

Answer (score 3):

I had the problem again and my above solution did not work.  If that is true for you and you are also using Anaconda on a Mac with El Capitan, try this:

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/RMG graphviz`
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/RMG pydot
```

Answer (score 3):

What I did at the end after so many tries from what i saw here (pseudo sequence for it to work for networkx )  :

```
apt-get remove python-pydot
pip install pydotplus
apt-get install libcgraph6
apt-get install python-pygraphviz


# pip freeze | grep pydot
 pydotplus==2.0.2
# pip freeze | grep pyparsing
pyparsing==2.2.0
# pip freeze | grep graphviz
pygraphviz==1.2
# python -c 'import pydotplus'
#
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (Mac OS X 10.9 with Python 2.7.10 on Anaconda):

```
conda uninstall pydot
```

Then,

```
conda install pydot
```

Pyparsing is then downgraded (from 2.x to 1.5.7) upon pydot's installation.  Future Googlers: this allowed me to install and import Theano correctly.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX Mavericks the following did the trick... I got the same error but at the bottom there was also a complaint that the graphviz executable was not present...  I think the problem was i had installed graphviz prior to the other modules?

```
brew uninstall graphviz
brew install graphviz
```

Answer (score 1):

When other solutions do not work, this is a quick and dirty method to solve the probem:

This example is from python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Edit the file python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/visualize_util.py and comment the code segment below.

```
if not pydot.find_graphviz():
    raise ImportError('Failed to import pydot. You must install pydot'
                      ' and graphviz for `pydotprint` to work.')
```

find_graphviz() is redundant on newer versions of pydot, and the above call does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I also met the problem and my pydot==1.0.28 while pyparsing==2.2.0. I fixed the problem by downloading the newest pydot 1.2.3(tar.gz)from google and then install it offline. When I updated the pydot in ubuntu 14.04, it said the pydot 1.0.28 is the newest version. Therefore I download from the google the 1.2.3 version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to downgrade pyparsing from version 2.x to version 1.5.7 to get pydot to work correctly.

For win-64, using Conda, this worked for me:

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/Trentonoliphant pyparsing=1.5.7
```

I then disabled/uninstalled the 2.x version and reloaded pyparsing in my script:

```
pyparsing = reload(pyparsing)
pydot = reload(pydot)
```

To check whether you have the right version running:

```
print pyparsing.__version__
```