# Why is pydot unable to find GraphViz's executables in Windows 8?

Tags: graphviz, scikit-learn, pygraphviz, pydot

I have GraphViz 2.32 installed in Windows 8 and have added C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.32\bin to the System PATH variable. Still pydot is unable to find its executables.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    graph.write_png('example1_graph.png')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pydot.py", line 1809, in <lambda>
    lambda path, f=frmt, prog=self.prog : self.write(path, format=f, prog=prog))
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pydot.py", line 1911, in write
    dot_fd.write(self.create(prog, format))
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pydot.py", line 1953, in create
    'GraphViz\'s executables not found' )
InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

I found this https://code.google.com/p/pydot/issues/detail?id=65 but am unable to get the problem solved.

Comment: You can now visualize trees without installing dot with ``sklearn.tree.plot_tree``

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This happened because I had installed graphviz after I had installed pydot. Hence, pydot wasn't able to find it. Reinstalling it in the correct order solved the problem.

Comment: The order in which `pydot` and GraphViz are installed does not make a difference to whether `pydot` can find GraphViz. GraphViz executables should be in the current path, in order for `pydot` to be able to detect them.

Comment: Order does not matters :)

Comment: Order does not matter

Answer (score 77):

The problem is that the path to GraphViz was not found by the pydot module as shown in the traceback:

> 'GraphViz\'s executables not found'

I solved this problem on my windows 7 machine by adding the GraphViz bin directory to my computer's PATH.  Then restarting my python IDE to use the updated path.

1. Install GraphViz if you haven't already (I used the MSI download)
2. Get the path for gvedit.exe (for me it was "C:\Program Files
   (x86)\Graphviz2.34\bin\")
3. Add this path to the computer's PATH
4. One way to get to environment settings to set your path is to click on each of these button/menu options: start->computer->system
   properties->advanced settings->environment variables
5. Click Edit User path
6. Add this string to the end of your Variable value list (including
   semicolon):  **;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.34\bin**
7. Click OK
8. Restart your Python IDE

Comment: In my Windows 8  system I was getting error until I realized that in Windows 8 I shouldn't use the quotation marks (") around the path. After removing them everything went nice.

Comment: This solved my problem on my anaconda installation; faced a lot of issue trying to get 'Graphviz' installed and added as a Path variable. The 'msi' route worked, but both the 'pip', 'conda' install route failed.

Answer (score 69):

On Mac `brew install graphviz` solved the problem for me.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: sudo aptitude install graphviz works respectively on ubuntu (18)

Answer (score 25):

I tried adding PATH via Control Panel, but restarting the command prompt is also needed. The following also works for updating the path in a Notebook session without exiting:

```
import os     

os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
```

Comment: You don't have to restart the whole computer, just the program that you want to use. Which is probably the command prompt you are running the notebook server from.

Comment: It is working in windows 10 machine. Thanks for sharing this code

Comment: amazing! it helped! i tried everything - but this solved it! thank you!

Answer (score 20):

in my case answer from Sadik
[pydot and graphviz error: Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951748/pydot-and-graphviz-error-couldnt-import-dot-parser-loading-of-dot-files-will) worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS

`sudo apt-get install python-pydot`

Comment: you'd better use `virtualenv`

Answer (score 9):

You need to install from [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and then just add the path of folder where you installed Graphviz and its bin directory to system environments path.

Answer (score 9):

For windows 8.1 & python 2.7 , I fixed the problem by following below steps

1 . Download and install graphviz-2.38.msi https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html

2 . Set the path variable

Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > Path > Edit
add 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin'

3. Restart your currently running application that requires the path

Comment: This solved it for me. Note: as already running applications might not automatically adapt to the updated environment, you should restart any application that requires the new path (see [How do you add a windows environment variable without rebooting](https://serverfault.com/questions/8855/how-do-you-add-a-windows-environment-variable-without-rebooting)).

Answer (score 6):

I'm working on Windows 10 with Anaconda 3.6.5. I have not admin rights, so if someone is under the circumstances like me  this solution works perfectly.

The path for my graphviz is looks
`C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Library\bin\graphviz`

In Spyder or in Jupyter type the following:

`import os
os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep)`

This will lists all the path in you environment. Take a look to them, if your graphviz path is not here, then go find it and copy the path, like above in my example.
Then type the following:
`os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + 'C:\\Users\\User_Name\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\Library\\bin\\graphviz'`

That's all, but note that you have to run these command every time if you restart kernel

Answer (score 4):

Add dot.exe to your path.
right click my computer > advanced system settings > environment variables > high light 'path' > edit 
then append everything in the quotes to path ";C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.34\bin\" depending on where you installed Graphviz ofcourse.Then restart the python shell and type.

> > > import pydot
> > >       pydot.find_graphviz()
> > >       Make sure there is a slash after 'bin' so it gets everything from inside the folder, I tried with out the slash and the above code returned nothing, however after adding the slash it returned the graphviz executables it needed and their paths.

Comment: I followed your instructions in Windows 10, but Windows did not add my module path (which is in google drive) to the path list even though it showed at the Window. One way to check if your path is actually added to path list is to open a new terminal and run "path".

Answer (score 4):

For me: (Win10, Anaconda3)
Make sure you have done "conda install graphviz"

I have to add to the PATH: C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\Library\bin\graphviz

To modify PATH go to Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables > Path > Edit > New

MAKE SURE TO RESTART YOUR IDE AFTER THIS.
It should work

Answer (score 2):

In Windows, even after installing graphviz-2.38.msi, you can add your own path in pydot.py (found under site-package folder)

```
 if os.sys.platform == 'win32':

    # Try and work out the equivalent of "C:\Program Files" on this
    # machine (might be on drive D:, or in a different language)
    #

    if os.environ.has_key('PROGRAMFILES'):

        # Note, we could also use the win32api to get this
        # information, but win32api may not be installed.

        path = os.path.join(os.environ['PROGRAMFILES'], 'ATT', 'GraphViz', 'bin')

    else:

        #Just in case, try the default...
        path = r"C:\PYTHON27\GraphViz\bin"  # add here.
```

Comment: I should notice that the else clause you've pointed is not reached always. So I added explicit path at the start of the `find_grapviz()`. Very dirty solution of course, but stupid time waste I've made while trying to get things working is so irritating. So this is in fact good hack.

Answer (score 2):

## I too had the same issue and I finally resolved it by having a look at the library.

The library considers making the path set as **C:\Program Files\ATT\Graphviz\bin** but by default Graphviz is installed to *C:\Program Files(x86)\Graphviz* undergoing the 32-bit criteria hence the **pydot** fails in getting the required path.
Simply shift the directory as required by the script and you're good to go.

P.S.:- Consider making the equivalent changes to the Environmnet Variable.

P.S.S:- Also check if Graphviz is directly under Program Files(x86) or under ATT.

Answer (score 1):

I am running a Windows 10 machine and had some problems, too. 
I installed graphviz via msi installer. Adding via System settings did not work for me.

I removed the installation with the msi and used [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/), a windows package manager.
Removing the installed version is necessary, otherwise chocolatey won't install.

Now it runs fine. I would recommend doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did for the above mentioned problem. I'm using windows 10 os and python 3.6.5

1. Install PIP by [clicking here](https://youtu.be/AVCcFyYynQY)
2. open command prompt and type command "pip install graphviz"
3. go to my computer(this pc) and search with the keyword "graphviz"
4. open the graphviz folder and copy its path and save it in notepad
5. In graphviz look for the bin folder and copy the folder by right click of your mouse
6. now again head back to my computer and search for "pydotplus"
7. a folder named *pydotplus* is displayed. Open it and paste the copy of bin folder (of Graphviz) that you copied earlier
8. head to control panel>system and security> system settings> advanced settings> environmental variables> add new path
9. add the path that you copied in notepad and click a series of "ok"

that's it now you can enjoy using graphviz

Comment: anyone have any idea why my graphviz folder has no bin folder? only __pycache__ and the .py files

Answer (score 1):

install Graphviz here and add its bin path solved my problem

https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html

pip install Graphviz itself seems inadequate

Answer (score 1):

Some things to know about graphviz:

1. graphviz is not only a python module, it's also a standalone program.  I believe you need both to make graphviz to work.
2. The standalone graphviz program was originally developed by AT&T, open sourced, then abandoned.  The current maintainers of the package forgot to include Windows registry entries so Python can find the program executable.
3. Line 620 of pydotplus\graphviz.py includes a backup path to look for graphviz if it isn't found in the registry.  It uses the old ATT file path.  Update the file path to what is on your machine (you will need to have administrator privileges) and graphviz should work with pydotplus.

Example:

`# Just in case, try the default...
path = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin"`

Answer (score 1):

In "pydot.py" (located in ...\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages), replace:

```
def get_executable_extension():
    # type: () -> str
    if is_windows():
        return '.bat' if is_anacoda() else '.exe'
    else:
        return ''
```

with:

```
def get_executable_extension():
    # type: () -> str
    if is_windows():
        return '.exe'
    else:
        return ''
```

There does not seem to be any eason to add ".bat" when the system is "Windows/Anaconda" vs "Windows" and there may be no ".bat" associated with the ".exe". This seems better than adding a ".bat" for every executable pydot calls...

Comment: This worked for me, associated with another step: add the folder containing the dot.exe executable file in the path variable.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and noticed that it was printing my PATH with two sets of double-quotes.  I worked around the problem by adding the following to Line 1959 of:

```
C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\pydot.py

self.progs[prog] = os.path.normpath(self.progs[prog][1:-1])
```

Obviously not the best fix but it got me through the day.

Answer (score 0):

I found a manual solution:
sudo apt-get install graphviz

graph.write('test.dot')
dot -Tps test.dot -o outfile.ps

You can the files here: https://github.com/jecs89/LearningEveryDay/tree/master/GP

Answer (score 0):

Tried all installation sequence as described in all solutions/posting/blogs, finally realized anaconda was not able to read the Environment variables. Closed Anaconda and Spyder. Then opened Anaconda in Administrator mode (on Windows 64 bit OS machine) and then opened Spyder. Script worked fine with PYDOT calls.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using a windows machine, I am on a linux platform. I ran across this executable-not-found issue in the context of using the python package pyAgrum for plotting bayesian networks. pyAgrum uses graphviz to plot the networks. I installed pyagrum and graphviz using the anaconda platform in a python 3.6.4 environment (i.e. `conda install <package name>`).

I found the executables in `/conda/envs/<environment name>/bin` directory. So, it was just a matter of getting my notebook kernel to find them.

If you `import os`, use the command `os.environ['PATH'].split(os.pathsep)` to see the executable paths in which your environment is looking. If the path containing your graphviz executables isn't in there, you can add it by doing the following: `os.environ['PATH'] += os.pathsep + <path to executables>`.

I imagine this solution will work outside of my context. The main downside to this solution is that you need to do it every time you restart the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

you can use pydotplus instead of pydot.then follow the belows:

First, find `C:\Users\zhangqianyuan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\pydotplus`

Second, open `graphviz.py`

Third, find line 1925 - line 1972, find the function `def create(self, prog=None, format='ps'):`

Final, in the function:

1. find:

   ```
   if prog not in self.progs:
       raise InvocationException(
           'GraphViz\'s executable "%s" not found' % prog)
   ```

   `

   ```
   if not os.path.exists(self.progs[prog]) or \
           not os.path.isfile(self.progs[prog]):
       raise InvocationException(
           'GraphViz\'s executable "{}" is not'
           ' a file or doesn\'t exist'.format(self.progs[prog])
       )
   ```
2. between the two blocks add this(Your Graphviz's executable path):

   `self.progs[prog] = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/gvedit.exe"`
3. after adding the result is:

   ```
   if prog not in self.progs:
       raise InvocationException(
           'GraphViz\'s executable "%s" not found' % prog)

   self.progs[prog] = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/gvedit.exe"

   if not os.path.exists(self.progs[prog]) or \
           not os.path.isfile(self.progs[prog]):
       raise InvocationException(
           'GraphViz\'s executable "{}" is not'
           ' a file or doesn\'t exist'.format(self.progs[prog])
       )
   ```
4. save the changed file then you can run it successfully.
5. you'd better save it as bmp file because png file will not work.
   [image: picture is here]

Comment: Why twice the same answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312534/graphvizs-executables-are-not-found-python-3-4/55507373#55507373 (i.e. double maintenance), better crosslink to other answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to mess around with path variables (e.g. if you are no admin) and if you are working on windows, you can do the following which solved the problem for me.

Open `graphviz.py` (likely located in `...Anaconda\pkgs\graphviz***\Library\bin`) in an  editor. If you cant find it you might be able to open it via the error message.

Go to the fuction `__find_executables` and replace:

```
elif os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, prg + '.exe')):
   if was_quoted:
      progs[prg] = '"' + os.path.join(path, prg + '.exe') + '"'
   else:
      progs[prg] = os.path.join(path, prg + '.exe')
```

with

```
elif os.path.exists(os.path.join(path, prg + '.bat')):
   if was_quoted:
      progs[prg] = '"' + os.path.join(path, prg + '.bat') + '"'
   else:
      progs[prg] = os.path.join(path, prg + '.bat')
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is easy, you just need to download and install the Graphviz, from [here](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html).

Then set the path variable to the bin directory, in my case it was `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin`. Last, do the `conda install python-graphviz` and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

On Anaconda distro, pip install did not work. I did a `pip uninstall graphviz`, `pip uninstall pydot`, and then I did `conda install graphviz` and then `conda install pydot`, in this order, and then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I used conda install python-graphviz
then
conda install pydot
and then
conda install pydot plus
and then it worked.

So:

```
conda install python-graphviz
conda install pydot
conda install pydotplus
```

Answer (score 0):

after doing all the installation of graphviz, adding to the PATH of environment variables, you need to add these two lines:

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried several ways and all failed on Windows 10 and finally this worked for me:
Try to install it directly from graphviz website, just google "install graphviz" and I believe it will be the first option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).