# InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found (Python)

Tags: python, graphviz

Getting error calling `pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data` in code below:

```
from IPython.display import Image  

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf,
                                out_file=None,
                                feature_names=iris.feature_names,
                                class_names=iris.target_names,
                                filled=True,
                                rounded=True,
                                special_characters=True)  
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

The error output:

```
File "C:\Users\ss\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 1960, in create 'GraphViz\'s executables not found')
InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphviz's executables are not found (Python 3.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312534/graphvizs-executables-are-not-found-python-3-4)

Answer (score 1):

As [pydotplus](https://github.com/carlos-jenkins/pydotplus#requirements) states in its requirements, you need [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) installed in your system.