# How can I solve the path error in graphviz?

Tags: python, neural-network, spyder, graphviz

I am trying to develop a neural network in spyder using keras and graphviz. I am beginner in this work. How can I solve this error?

```
ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'network.gv'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

Comment: Install the graphviz path and see to it that the bin directory of graphviz is in your path. Which OS are you using.? What happens when you give the command `dot -V` in a terminal window?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on Mac OS Catalina after attempting the install using Conda. However, running `brew install graphviz` fixed everything just fine.

See [this Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312534/graphvizs-executables-are-not-found-python-3-4) for other ideas.