# Graphviz executables not found using Anaconda virtualenv

Tags: pycharm, anaconda, virtualenv, graphviz, pydot

*I know this question has been asked many times, but so far none of the proposed solutions helped for me.*

I am using Keras for training an autoencoder. I want to save the model to a png-file by using the `plot_model` method from `keras.utils`. When doing such, I get the following errors:

[image: Graphviz error]

As one can see, I am using Anaconda3, I use a virtualenv called 'py37'. What's more, I installed Graphviz (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38`) and installed `graphviz`, `python-graphviz` and `pydot` to my virtualenv 'py37' (not to the root of Anaconda). I did so via `conda install x`.

I tried many things, amongst others adding the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` to my user path, as proposed via this [Stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312534/graphvizs-executables-are-not-found-python-3-4), which did not help (even after restarting my computer).

I have little experience with these kind of things, so maybe I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried everything as identified in other posts (which I am not repeating here).

Finally, the problem got resolved when I added `GRAPHVIZ_DOT` enivironment variable pointing to `dot.exe` as explained in
https://enterprise-architecture.org/downloads?id=208

Hope this helps

Also with new version of Keras, make sure you are referring to

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
```

and not

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
```