# Write png with pydotplus doesn't work in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I try to make png from decision tree that i made before from a [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zHjUJb_32DG_-xeCWoa8XQEIl4FWaw6Z/view?usp=sharing). Using package pydotplus, I want to save the png in my local storage and show it. It work in google colab, but it error in jupyter. It said

> GraphViz's executables not found

This is my code

```
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz 
from six import StringIO
from IPython.display import Image  
import pydotplus

feature_cols = ['Pregnancies', 'Glucose', 'BloodPressure', 'SkinThickness', 'Insulin',
       'BMI', 'DiabetesPedigreeFunction', 'Age']
dot_data = StringIO()
export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dot_data,  
                filled=True, rounded=True,
                special_characters=True, feature_names = feature_cols, class_names=['0','1'])
graph = pydotplus.graphviz.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
graph.write_png('diabetes.png')
Image(graph.create_png())
```

The error show in jupyter

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvocationException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [46], in <cell line: 14>()
     12 graph = pydotplus.graphviz.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
     13 # graph.write_png('file//diabetes.png')
---> 14 Image(graph.create_png())

File ~\.conda\envs\butterfly\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py:1797, in Dot.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>(f, prog)
   1792 # Automatically creates all the methods enabling the creation
   1793 # of output in any of the supported formats.
   1794 for frmt in self.formats:
   1795     self.__setattr__(
   1796         'create_' + frmt,
-> 1797         lambda f=frmt, prog=self.prog: self.create(format=f, prog=prog)
   1798     )
   1799     f = self.__dict__['create_' + frmt]
   1800     f.__doc__ = (
   1801         '''Refer to the docstring accompanying the'''
   1802         ''''create' method for more information.'''
   1803     )

File ~\.conda\envs\butterfly\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py:1959, in Dot.create(self, prog, format)
   1957     self.progs = find_graphviz()
   1958     if self.progs is None:
-> 1959         raise InvocationException(
   1960             'GraphViz\'s executables not found')
   1962 if prog not in self.progs:
   1963     raise InvocationException(
   1964         'GraphViz\'s executable "%s" not found' % prog)

InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

I hope you guys can help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my question.

This question problem is in the file graphviz. I can fix this problem by download package from graphviz website. If you download from `pip install pydotplus` or `pip install graphviz` maybe you get the same error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvocationException                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [46], in <cell line: 14>()
     12 graph = pydotplus.graphviz.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())  
     13 # graph.write_png('file//diabetes.png')
---> 14 Image(graph.create_png())

File ~\.conda\envs\butterfly\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py:1797, in Dot.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>(f, prog)
   1792 # Automatically creates all the methods enabling the creation
   1793 # of output in any of the supported formats.
   1794 for frmt in self.formats:
   1795     self.__setattr__(
   1796         'create_' + frmt,
-> 1797         lambda f=frmt, prog=self.prog: self.create(format=f, prog=prog)
   1798     )
   1799     f = self.__dict__['create_' + frmt]
   1800     f.__doc__ = (
   1801         '''Refer to the docstring accompanying the'''
   1802         ''''create' method for more information.'''
   1803     )

File ~\.conda\envs\butterfly\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py:1959, in Dot.create(self, prog, format)
   1957     self.progs = find_graphviz()
   1958     if self.progs is None:
-> 1959         raise InvocationException(
   1960             'GraphViz\'s executables not found')
   1962 if prog not in self.progs:
   1963     raise InvocationException(
   1964         'GraphViz\'s executable "%s" not found' % prog)

InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

The problem is in the library itself. So, try to download zip file from graphviz website and direct the extract file bin in my computer. This [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5bTZdSjFE4E) will help you to the detail

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Hello Try these answers in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312534/graphvizs-executables-are-not-found-python-3-4), Maybe this is helpful. Or you can try importing OpenCV or PIL or matplotlib and write the variable as a png file. Install OpenCV library before doing this. You can do it by

```
#Installing OpenCV library
conda install -c anaconda opencv

#importing opencv 
import cv2

#writing a variable as an image but it should be in an array format to achieve this.
cv2.imwrite("graph.png", graph)
```

Comment: Still not work. It said the data type is not a numpy array

Comment: Try converting the variable graph to an array and then write it as image. Can you see the plot in Jupiter without saving it, Have you tried that?

Comment: I using np.asarray(), but it still error. It said Overload resolution failed: img data type = 17 is not supported and Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'

Comment: what type is your graph variable? Try plotting using matplotlib.

Comment: it said pydotplus.graphviz.Dot