# tenserflow kernel keeps dying after installing "pydot (version 1.4.1)" and "python-graphviz (version 0.8.4)"

Tags: tensorflow

I installed "pydot (version 1.4.1)" and "python-graphviz (version 0.8.4)" to my tensorflow environment in anaconda. Now my tenserflow kernel keeps dying. I did get this warning once when I was trying to import the tensorflow libraries.

C:\Users\lbasnet\Anaconda3\envs\tflow\lib\site-packages\h5py_*init*_.py:40: UserWarning: h5py is running against HDF5 1.10.5 when it was built against 1.10.4, this may cause problems '{0}.{1}.{2}'.format(*version.hdf5_built_version_tuple)

Any idea how I can resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved by myself. I uninstalled h5py  `pip uninstall h5py` and reinstalled it `pip install h5py`

If you were trying to get `plot_model` to work and ended up with the above issue I faced, the following links can be very helpful to get "pydot" and "graphviz" to work.

1. [Link 1 for "pydot"](https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras/issues/7#issuecomment-394536439)
2. [Link 2 for "pydot"](https://github.com/XifengGuo/CapsNet-Keras/issues/7#issuecomment-370745440)
3. [Link 3 for "graphviz"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312534/graphvizs-executables-are-not-found-python-3-4), refer to the answer by Silvia Bakalova if you are a windows user.