# "dot.exe" not found in path. Pydot on Python (Windows 7)

Tags: python, path, pydot

I'm having trouble running Python's pydot on Windows 7.

I installed pydot with:  `conda install -c rmg pydot=1.2.2`

I have graphviz installed under `../Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/`

When I run the following script I get an error saying

> ```
> "dot.exe" not found in path
> ```

```
import pydot
graph = pydot.Dot(graph_type='digraph')
node_a = pydot.Node("Node A", style="filled", fillcolor="red")
node_b = pydot.Node("Node B", style="filled", fillcolor="green")
node_c = pydot.Node("Node C", style="filled", fillcolor="#0000ff")
node_d = pydot.Node("Node D", style="filled", fillcolor="#976856")
graph.add_node(node_a)
graph.add_node(node_b)
graph.add_node(node_c)
graph.add_node(node_d)
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(node_a, node_b))
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(node_b, node_c))
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(node_c, node_d))
graph.add_edge(pydot.Edge(node_d, node_a, label="and back we go again", labelfontcolor="#009933", fontsize="10.0", color="blue"))
graph.write_png('example2_graph.png')

Exception: "dot.exe" not found in path.
```

I have tried this solution: *[Permanently adding a file path to sys.path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257747/permanently-adding-a-file-path-to-sys-path-in-python/12257807#12257807)*, by adding the `my-paths.pth` file with a line pointing to 
`../Graphiv2.38/bin/` where the `dot.exe` file is located. But I still get the error.

What else can I try?

Comment: You need to add the absolute path to dot.exe in your  enviorment variable %PATH% and not the relative path. If this doesn't work, update your post with a screenshoot of your %PATH% dump. Very important, Windows pathes only works with backslashes.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I followed the instructions given in [this blog](http://www.codesofinterest.com/2017/02/visualizing-model-structures-in-keras.html).

Then I installed graphviz from [here](http://www.graphviz.org/download/) and added C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin to `PATH`.

Next I did:

```
conda install pydot-ng
```

And finally in my notebook I added the two lines below.

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'
```

Comment: This solution worked for me too, only change that the download now can be found on: http://www.graphviz.org/download/

Comment: Although I added manually Graphviz to PATH, only adding the two lines solved the problem for me.

Comment: How did you download graphviz from http://www.graphviz.org/download/? I'm having a hard time

Comment: might want to note that you might not need to conda install pydot-ng. That rolled back my version of python which took some work to undo. the import os and os.environ worked like a charm

Comment: Please don't ignore his last point:                                                            
import os  and
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin/'

Comment: You can install the binaries with `conda install graphviz` and then put those in your path instead of `Program Files`.

Comment: graphviz 2.44.1 on windows was not working. i uninstalled 2.44.1 and installed 2.38 and it worked

Answer (score 13):

Type `conda install pydot graphviz` in cmd, and then add the executables location directory `C:\Anaconda3\pkgs\graphviz-2.38-hfd603c8_2\Library\bin\graphviz` to your system path variable. That works!

Comment: It works! It seems there is no need to change the system path to use ``graphviz`` and ``pydot`` in a ``conda`` environment and the associated python.

Comment: This method solved this issue for me as well—no need to add Envir Vars, as @SaltedFishLZ mentions.

Answer (score 11):

Don't use the following command if you are on Python 3:

```
conda install pydot-ng
```

This will take your installation to Python 2.7

Use instead

```
conda install graphviz
```

Answer (score 3):

Other solutions didn't work for me, and I figured out *pydot* tried to run a hardcoded `dot.bat` so I just created `dot.bat` wrapper nearby `dot.exe` and it worked:

```
@echo off
dot %*
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graph_models.html) to generate the model graph for your Django application, I did this and it worked:

```
pip install django-extensions
pip install pyparsing
pip install graphviz
pip install pydot
conda install graphviz
```

Add `django-extensions` to you `INSTALLED_APPS` and then add `C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\pkgs\graphviz-2.38.0-4\Library\bin\graphviz` to my system path variable.
Then finally and normally:

```
python manage.py graph_models -a -g -o pic.png
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having trouble with this and found out that if you're using the Visual Studio Code integrated command line then you should make sure to restart Visual Studio Code (you might need to only restart the command line) otherwise the PATH changes won't take place...

Comment: I think it applies to any editor. With the PyCharm too, you need to restart it.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of cases, when resources are not found by programs on your system, follow these quick steps:

- Run a simple command prompt, type and execute the needed command (can be 'dot.exe')
- If yes, your system is nicely configured and perhaps due to a hard configured way in your code, executables are not found (need a specific location for files to be found for instance: program check for C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\pkgs\graphviz and you put binaries in C:\Program Files\graphviz).
- If no, you need to add it manually. In environment variable add the directory that contains the binaries (for instance 'my_location\graphviz\bin'). If you need it for whole users of the computer, put it in the system 'Path' (need to disconnect the users accounts to be considered), else in the user 'Path' (need to reopen the needed program). Then check it by re-opening a command prompt and typing the command.

If it's not working... you mistyped something =)

Some advices: Rapid Environment Editor is pretty cool for configuring windows environment variables ;)

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 installing the binaries with `sudo apt-get install graphviz` led to `dot` being placed under `/usr/bin/dot` (it might go to `/usr/local/bin/dot` per their [installation guide](https://enterprise-architecture.org/downloads?id=208)). 
After doing:

```
pip3 install pydot-ng
```

and adding the following lines (similar to @Ernest's answer in Linux) to the script it worked:

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + "/usr/bin/dot"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had some very bad experiences with conda, so avoid the mess it causes at all cost.

Fortunately every answer here is using conda unnecessarily. You can simply install this package with `pip install pydot` then after adding `Graphviz` to your path as described in the accepted answer, this error is resolved. (Windows)