# SQLAlchemy ER diagram in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, entity-relationship

Does anyone know a way to make an ER diagram from SQLAlchemy models in python 3. I found sqlalchemy_schemadisplay, which is python 2 because of pydot and ERAlchemy which is also python 2 only.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can try [eralchemy](https://github.com/Alexis-benoist/eralchemy).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import pandas as pd
from eralchemy import render_er

from sqlalchemy import (MetaData, Table, Column)    
metadata = MetaData()

# create your own model ....
users = Table('users', metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer(), primary_key=True),
    Column('username', String(15), nullable=False, unique=True),
)    
orders = Table('orders', metadata,
    Column('order_id', Integer()),
    Column('user_id', ForeignKey('users.user_id')),
)
# add your own table ....

# Show ER model from here
filename = 'mymodel.png'
render_er(metadata, filename)
imgplot = plt.imshow(mpimg.imread(filename))
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (15,10)
plt.show()
```

Then it shows the model.

[image]

Those modules I used are:

<kbd><kbd>**`Software`**</kbd>    <kbd>**`Version`**</kbd>  

<kbd>`Python`</kbd>      <kbd>`3.4.5 64bit`</kbd>

<kbd>`IPython`</kbd>     <kbd>`5.1.0`</kbd>      

<kbd>`OS`</kbd>          <kbd>`Windows 10`</kbd> 

<kbd>`sqlalchemy`</kbd>  <kbd>`1.1.5`</kbd>      

<kbd>`eralchemy`</kbd>   <kbd>`1.1.0`</kbd>      

<kbd>`matplotlib`</kbd>  <kbd>`2.0.0`</kbd></kbd>

Comment: How did you install `erlalchemy` on Windows 10 with 64-bit?

Comment: It is no problem use "pip install" in my virtual env as above. You could to get help by raise issue on https://github.com/Alexis-benoist/eralchemy/issues.

Comment: Probably not working on Windows with 64-bit Python. ([link](https://github.com/pygraphviz/pygraphviz/issues/40#issuecomment-349777183))

Answer (score 18):

As mentioned in an earlier answer, [sqlalchemy_schemadisplay](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/SchemaDisplay) is a fantastically simple tool. Here's the basic how you would use it:

```
from sqlalchemy_schemadisplay import create_schema_graph
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

graph = create_schema_graph(metadata=MetaData('postgres://user:pwd@host/database'))
graph.write_png('my_erd.png')
```

Comment: Supposing you want your outputs to look not-horrible you can also pass attributes through to the underlying graphviz via `graph.set(attr, value)`. e.g. `graph.set('scale', 2)` . Graphviz attributes are [documented here](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html)

Comment: Very helpful! @nerdstrike

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "dot" not found in path. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to install `graphiz` on your machine @AkhilS. Maybe this can help? ["dot.exe" not found in path. Pydot on Python (Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632486/dot-exe-not-found-in-path-pydot-on-python-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

[SQLAlchemy_SchemaDisplay](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy_schemadisplay/) works for me, too.

On Windows I installed [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) and these requirements via [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/):

- pydot
- sqlalchemy
- sqlalchemy_schemadisplay
- graphviz

Then I added the Grapviz binary (bin) folder to the path and ran the code from the example at https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/wiki/SchemaDisplay

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [sqlalchemy_data_model_visualizer](https://github.com/Dicklesworthstone/sqlalchemy_data_model_visualizer) which is more modern and outputs svg through graphviz:

1. Install graphviz on your system (e.g. `apt install graphviz` on Ubuntu)
2. `pip install sqlalchemy_data_model_visualizer`
3. create a script where you import your models and render a svg:

```
from yourapp.yourdb import Model1, Model2

models = [Model1, Model2]
generate_data_model_diagram(models, "diagram")
```

That should generate `diagram.svg`

Answer (score 0):

`eralchemy` is not maintained anymore and does not work with SQLAlchemy > 1.4

Right now `eralchemy2` is more up to date and has similar installation steps. 
Worth a try: https://github.com/maurerle/eralchemy2

I tested with Python 3.11 and SQLAlchemy 2.0+ on Windows, and it works.