# Python/sqlite3: is there a way to make database schema figure?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

Very new to sql and thus new to sqlite3. I'm setting up a relational database and need a visual for peer review prior to populating with actual data. (That is, I am setting up all the tables and fields, with primary and foreign keys, but there are no records for now.)

Is there a way to make a figure that visually shows the relationships between the tables? (Example internet grab below--or maybe linked because I am new user.) Using sqlite3 and python. Bonus points if it looks better than the crummy Access visual!

[schema plot figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BOYx.jpg)

Comment: @DaFi4 - I'm looking for open source and in python (although that software looks pretty slick)

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/ERAlchemy/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981986/sqlalchemy-er-diagram-in-python-3/46020917

Comment: @DaFi4, I like ERAlchemy, thanks. If you write it up as an answer below, I will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one possible solution to making relational diagrams in Python is ERAlchemy. As of the time of this posting, I did not see any other pure Python solution.

https://pypi.org/project/ERAlchemy/

Comment: do you know if there is a way to get ERAlchemy to also show the foreign keys? (looks like the PK fieldnames are underlined)

Comment: yes, use the  ForeignKey decorator for Table.Column, such as ForeignKey ('foreigntablename.foreignfieldname'), for some example please see answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44981986/sqlalchemy-er-diagram-in-python-3/46020917

Answer (score 0):

Navicat has a product that you can use to import databases and display schemas. They have a trial version (see below). There's a stripped down version that you can use for free to depict schemas manually; the full license looks to be pretty pricey.

[image: Navicat]

Check it out here if you're using Mac - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/navicat-ess-12-for-sqlite/id1257394364?mt=12

You can get their trial version from the Navicat website - https://navicat.com/products