# Using django-extensions to generate a model graph in PNG format using Windows 10 (without using Conda or Anaconda)

Tags: python, django, pygraphviz, pydot

I am using [django-extensions](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation_instructions.html) to generate a model graph for my Django application.

My installation steps are the following:

```
$ pip install django-extensions
$ pip install pyparsing pydot
```

An installation of `pygraphviz` fails (as described) due to missing C extensions:

```
$ pip install pygraphviz # this does not work
```

Now, using the `pydot` option from the `graph_models` [documentation](https://django-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graph_models.html) works for `.dot` files:

```
$ python manage.py graph_models -a -I Device,Vehicle -o my_project_subsystem.dot
```

But creating PNG files breaks and indicates that `dot` is not on `PATH`:

```
$ python manage.py graph_models --pydot -a -g -o my_project_visualized.png
```

with an error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "dot" not found in path
```

A fix to this problem using `conda` and `pygraphviz` is provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48104765/3734059) answer.

But how can I create graphs with only using `pip` without using `anaconda`?
To me, it does not matter if use `pydot` or `pygraphviz`. I just want to create models into PNG files.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["dot.exe" not found in path. Pydot on Python (Windows 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632486/dot-exe-not-found-in-path-pydot-on-python-windows-7)

Answer (score 3):

It took a while but I got it working using the following steps:

1. Install django extensions via `$ pip install django-extensions==3.1.5`
2. Install pydotplus via `$ pip install pydotplus==2.0.2`
3. Install GraphViz via [installer](https://graphviz.org/download/) and MANUALLY add it to the user `PATH`

Include `django_extensions` in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_extensions',
    ...
)
```

Run command:

`$ python manage.py graph_models -a -o myapp_models.png`

Answer (score 0):

You must download and install apllication
https://graphviz.org/download/
helped me after fighting all other solutions

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).