# ROS "rqt_graph" command not working on windows 10

Tags: ros

I have installed ROS1 NOETIC in my windows 10 machine but I am unable to run "rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph" command to see the graph. Getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\rqt_graph\ros_graph.py", line 284, in _update_rosgraph
    self._refresh_rosgraph()
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\rqt_graph\ros_graph.py", line 289, in _refresh_rosgraph
    self._update_graph_view(self._generate_dotcode())
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\rqt_graph\ros_graph.py", line 308, in _generate_dotcode
    return self.dotcode_generator.generate_dotcode(
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\rqt_graph\dotcode.py", line 914, in generate_dotcode
    dotcode = dotcode_factory.create_dot(dotgraph)
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\qt_dotgraph\pydotfactory.py", line 175, in create_dot
    dot = graph.create_dot()
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1722, in new_method
    return self.create(
  File "c:\opt\ros\noetic\x64\lib\site-packages\pydot.py", line 1922, in create
    raise OSError(*args)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] "dot" not found in path.
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40632486/dot-exe-not-found-in-path-pydot-on-python-windows-7

Comment: hi @Fruchtzwerg that is for windows 7 and things are different in windows 10. I saw the solutions on the given thread and I think i can try fixing it in windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Solution was very simple. As I had used chocolatery for ROS installation in the windows 10, I can use the same for installing "graphviz" as below

```
choco install graphviz
```