# How to correctly execute 'dot' from Graphviz in Spyder (Anaconda) in a macOS?

Tags: python, macos, spyder, graphviz, dot

**Question: How to correctly execute 'dot' from Graphviz in Spyder (Anaconda) in macOS?**

Context: I know this topic has been already addressed in other posts:

- [How to use Graphviz with Anaconda/Spyder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869258/how-to-use-graphviz-with-anaconda-spyder)
- [(Python) ValueError: Program dot not found in path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987353/python-valueerror-program-dot-not-found-in-path)
- [Exception: “dot” not found in path in python on mac](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/4911)

But I have tried all the recommendations on these posts and I still get the errors:

```
Exception: “dot” not found in path in python on mac

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dot'

ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Kdot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'FileName'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

I have already installed Graphviz, and as you can see below, *dot* is working:

[image]

Above can be seenn that by typing:

```
dot -V
```

It returns the version I have installed. As well as when typing:

```
which dot
```

It returns the location of the file (i.e., /usr/local/bin). I have tried several things with this path.

1. Add it to the path in Spyder:

[image]

2. I added to the main system PATH:

[image]

3. And I even run a script in Python trying to add the path from the code (I have tried it with and without 'dot' at the end of the path):

[image]

None of the above solutions worked for me. If anyone could give me some insights to solve this problem, I would really appreciate it.

As an example, you can try the code below, which is the one that gives me the error ([source](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html)):

```
import graphviz

dot = graphviz.Digraph(comment='The Round Table')

dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave')
dot.edges(['AB', 'AL'])
dot.edge('B', 'L', constraint='false')

dot.render('FileName', view=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from having in the main system path the location of the ".dot" executable and added it to the PATH from Spyder in PYTHONPATH manager, I tried several other things, I will summarize the steps that worked for me. I hope this works also for you.

- **Step 1**: I downloaded Anaconda from the [official site](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual#macos).
- **Step 2**: The version I installed was 1.10.0. This version had already pre-installed Spyder 4.1.5
- **Step 3**: I tried to run the example I gave in the description above, but appeared the same errors. I tried to install Graphviz using the command (from the Spyder console):

  conda install graphiz
- **Note**: When I used the above command, it took forever and appeared some problems with the environment with a message saying "solving environment ..." Then I decided to stop it (CTRL+C), and continue with Step 4.
- **Step 4**: I updated Anaconda and Spyder using respectively the following commands:

  conda update anaconda

  conda update spyder
- **Note**: I checked the Spyder version, and it was already 4.2.1 (before it was 4.1.5)
- **Step 5**: Now, I opened Spyder, and typed again the command:

  conda install graphiz
- **Note**: This time, at the beginning appeared a few warning messages, but after a minute it successfully installed.
- **Step 6**: I re-started the kernel, and run again the example, and this time it worked!!

Below you can see that Graphviz appears in the Anaconda environment (which before it didn't):

[image]

In the end, I executed this example:

```
import graphviz

dot = graphviz.Digraph(comment='The Round Table')

dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave')
dot.edges(['AB', 'AL'])
dot.edge('B', 'L', constraint='false')

dot.render('FileName', view=True)
```

And I obtained:

[image]