# How to install pydotplus for Python 3.5 on Windows64

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, conda, pydot

What is a proven method for installing pydotplus for Python 3.5 on a 64-bit Windows(10) system? So far I haven't had any luck using conda or a number of other approaches.

It appears there are several viable options for both Linux Ubuntu and Windows for Python 2.7. Unfortunately it's necessary for me to use this particular configuration, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try running anaconda prompt as 'administrator', then use:

> conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried for conda? According to https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pydotplus/files pydotplus is available from conda-forge for Windows x64 and Python 3.5. Typing

```
conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had definitely tried that earlier but for some reason it wasn't working. However, thanks to your response I took another look at my configuration to see why that particular install package wasn't running properly.

I originally used Anaconda to install a dual Python 2.7/3.5 environment and while I was always able to run 3.5 without any issues in an IDE (Jupyter Notebook in this instance), the current environment had still automatically defaulted to 2.7. The quick way to check for this via the command window is:

```
C:\Users\Username\Anaconda\envs>conda env list
```

which should produce something like:

```
# conda environments:
#
py27                   * C:\Users\Username\Anaconda\envs\py27
py35                     C:\Users\Username\Anaconda\envs\py35
```

Note that there will be '*' next to the environment that is currently active. To switch, simply type 'activate' followed by the new desired environment name and the change should immediately be verified by the command prompt that is returned:

```
C:\Users\Username\Anaconda\envs>activate py35

(py35) C:\Users\Username\Anaconda\envs>
```

After making the environment change, I reran the conda install package for pydotplus that you mentioned:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus
```

and it worked perfectly!

Two other quick things to consider when installing pydotplus to ensure that it interacts correctly with GraphViz in your particular environment:

1. Make sure you're running the most up to date version of scikit-learn. More info is provided on the official website (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html), including the quick update command: `conda update scikit-learn`
2. Verify that the GraphViz bin directory has been added to your User Path: ([Why is pydot unable to find GraphViz's executables in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438997/why-is-pydot-unable-to-find-graphvizs-executables-in-windows-8))

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this answer until now. On SO, people aren't notified when a new answer is posted, since its different than a forum. In any case, I'm glad my answer helped! Its typical if you find an answer helpful to upvote it as well, and if it answered your question, to click the green check mark to accept it (although it seems like your own answer is more complete, so you can actually accept your own answer if you'd like).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. here what I did was,
first I ran the anaconda prompt as administrator and then give the command,

```
**conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus**
```

it worked for me well