# Installing graphviz in Windows 10 with Anaconda3 and using it through a Jupyter Notebook/Python3

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, graphviz

I have been trying unsuccessfuly to use graphviz inside a Jupyter Notebook with Python3 kernel installed via Anaconda3.

When I make a call to graphviz I get the error message:

```
InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

I begun by installing graphviz using conda.  Since the exception persisted I installed again graphviz using pip.

There is a post that disccusses this problem in Stackoverflow here: [Why is pydot unable to find GraphViz's executables in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438997/why-is-pydot-unable-to-find-graphvizs-executables-in-windows-8)

I tried to follow the advice.

First I located the graphviz and added its path to the Environment path:

[image]

The path where graphviz is found in my PC is: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\bin\graphviz

There is no bin directory inside this folder.  The folder is flat without any subdirectories.

My system variables:

[image]

In the instructions provided in the aforementioned StackOverFlow post I am told:

> now again head back to my computer and search for "pydotplus"
>
> a folder named pydotplus is displayed. Open it and paste the copy of
>   bin folder (of Graphviz) that you copied earlier

I have installed pydotplus:

[image]

However when I search for pydotplus I can not find it:

[image]

When I call again graphviz from inside my Jupyter Notebook I get again the same exception.

```
from IPython.display import Image  
from sklearn import tree
import pydotplus

# Create DOT data
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(dt_clf_4, out_file=None, 
                                feature_names= features,  
                                class_names= 'malignant')

# Draw graph
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  

# Show graph
Image(graph.create_png())

InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not using pydot, but it seems to be using the same executable as graphviz. For me,
install graphviz using `conda install python-graphviz` fixes the missing graphviz executable issue.