# Where do I add Graphviz's Executable on a Mac

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz

I'm trying to use `Graphviz` but am getting the error message:

```
graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpdf', '-O', 'test-output/aoc.gv.pdf'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

The code I am running is cut and pasted from the documentation:

```
from graphviz import Digraph, Graph
dot = Digraph(comment='The Round Table')
dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')
dot.node('B', 'Sir Bedevere the Wise')
dot.node('L', 'Sir Lancelot the Brave')
dot.edges(['AB', 'AL'])
dot.edge('B', 'L', constraint='false')
dot.render('test-output/aoc.gv.pdf')
```

The file will output to the correct folder and the file is there and it has 170 bytes but it will not open. I have tried other extensions such as just 'gv' and they do not work either.  I'm using the latest version of `Graphviz` which is 0.10.1 and I have tried opening this file on a PC and it does not work on PC either (I have a Mac).  This problem is similar to

[Graphviz's executables are not found (Python 3.4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312534/graphvizs-executables-are-not-found-python-3-4)

and

[Why is pydot unable to find GraphViz's executables in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438997/why-is-pydot-unable-to-find-graphvizs-executables-in-windows-8)

However, there are major stumbling blocks to my understanding these posts.  Number one, I have very little understanding of how Python is executed on a computer, so I really don't even know what an environment variable is. Second, when they refer to computer's PATH I can only assume that they're talking about the directory of the file which is executing the `Graphviz` module, but I'm not sure about that.  So I've added this line of code:

```
import sys
str1 = "/library/frameworks/python.framework/versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphviz/"
sys.path.append(str1)
```

But that is not working.  Third, if I were to implement this step:

> Add this string to the end of your Variable value list (including semicolon): ;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.34\bin

Then I would have to translate that into its Mac counterpart and I'm not able to.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed the actual Graphviz (not a python package, but the actual program)? e.g. `brew install graphviz`?

Comment: Read http://www.linfo.org/path_env_var.html to understand how PATH works.  `brew` usually installs everything under `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: Where does Homebrew install Graphviz? I've yet to find one site that includes this critical information! It's not in /Applications.

Answer (score 9):

The diagnostic is saying that `dot` is not in your $PATH, it does not appear in any of the directories mentioned by that env var. You want to get to a point where trying the following command reports some version number:

```
$ dot -V
dot - graphviz version 2.40.1 (20161225.0304)
$
$ which dot
/usr/local/bin/dot
$
$ echo $PATH | tr : ' ' | fmt -w1 | grep local
/usr/local/bin
```

If you are not yet using Brew, you should. It's the easiest way to get this and many other programs onto your Mac. Visit https://brew.sh/ and follow the instructions. Then type:

```
$ brew install graphviz
...
$ /usr/local/bin/dot -V
```

That should work just fine. If `dot -V` says "not found" then simply append the proper directory to your PATH:

```
$ export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/bin"
```

If your bash shell can run it, then your python program should be able to, as well.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.  I already had homebrew installed but that doesn't matter because I don't understand how it works anyway.  When I put in the command `/usr/local/bin/dot -V` I got the error message: `/usr/local/bin/dot: No such file or directory`.  When I input `export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/bin"` I did not get an error message but the program will not work. I tried substituting PATH for the path that the module is in which is: `/Users/me/PycharmProjects/inference_engine2/inference2/proofs/other/` but that gave the message: `bad substitution`

Comment: It sounds like `dot` is not installed on your Mac. Use `$ brew install graphviz` to install it in the default location of /usr/local/bin.

Comment: I put in `brew install graphviz` and everything worked fine.  I did get this message `Error: The following directories are not writable by your user:
/usr/local/share/man/man3
/usr/local/share/man/man5
/usr/local/share/man/man7` But I'm not sure that is relevant.

Comment: Also when I write: `echo $PATH` I get:
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin/dot`

Comment: In short, at the documentation it says: "Make sure that the directory containing the dot executable is on your systems’ path." I just can't figure out what that means.

Comment: Over at this site: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/ I found this guy who is adding mysql with the following: export PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH".  So I tried something analogous like: `export PATH="/usr/local/graphviz/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/dot/bin:$PATH"`

Comment: Ok, here is something on my bash_profile.  It has: `PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"`. I need to find some way to alter that string so that graphviz will work. Any ideas?

Comment: ```brew install graphviz``` this help me! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved.  It took me a while to figure out that I had to download some non-pythonic software before I could get the pythonic software to work.

```
brew install graphviz
```

Was step 1 and I had done that before but I was getting an error message.  It told me to change ownership of some files so I did that. Then tried

```
brew install graphviz
```

again and that did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

I tried these commands to help me locate the DOT file path on my mac. It was not: "/usr/local/bin/dot" on my system.

```
dot -V

dot - graphviz version 2.49.2

which dot

/opt/homebrew/bin/dot
```

I had installed Graphviz, but I was still running into trouble finding the right path. I am using Protege, and I had to modify the path for OwlViz since it was displaying the entire hierarchy at (0,0). I copied the path that I got by running the which dot command to the OWLViz tab on the preference dialog, and restarted protege and it worked perfectly! Good luck!