# how to fix graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound in docker?

Tags: python, docker, graphviz

I have an error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphviz/backend.py", line 244, in pipe
    out, _ = run(cmd, input=data, capture_output=True, check=True, quiet=quiet)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/graphviz/backend.py", line 167, in run
    raise ExecutableNotFound(cmd)
graphviz.backend.ExecutableNotFound: failed to execute ['dot', '-Tpng'], make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH
```

In my Mac when I do:

```
dot -V
```

I get:

```
dot - graphviz version 2.47.3 (20210619.1520)
```

and when I do:

```
which dot
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/bin/dot
```

It seems that docker doesn't recognise this package though. I tried to do:

```
$ export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/bin"
```

as explained in [Where do I add Graphviz's Executable on a Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54966989/where-do-i-add-graphvizs-executable-on-a-mac)
but this doesn't solve the problem.

In the docker when I do:

```
pip install graphviz
```

It says:

```
Requirement already satisfied: graphviz in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.15)
```

how can I make the docker recognise the executable?
I can't do `brew install graphviz` inside the docker this command is accepted only in the Mac terminal but not in the docker.

Comment: The container has its own separate filesystem and runtime environment; it can't use binaries installed on the host outside Docker (especially on a Mac where the host and container run different operating systems).  You need to install the package in your image's Dockerfile, maybe using the Debian `apt-get` tool.

Comment: @DavidMaze How can I do that for a docker that is running?

Comment: Build a new image, stop and delete the existing container, and `docker run` a new one from the updated images.

Comment: @DavidMaze why can't I do that "on the fly" when the docker is running?

Comment: Because anything you change in the container filesystem will get lost as soon as the container exits; because you want to be able to check into source control the steps you need to do to build the image and container.  Also, deleting and recreating a container is pretty cheap and there's no reason to avoid it.

Comment: @DavidMaze I have no problem with that being gone after I finish the execution. (Similar to me doing pip install within the docker and not specifying it in advanced in the requirement.txt)

Answer (score 2):

I assume that at some point you have python installed in your docker container. In possession of this, you should have in your project a file called `requirements.txt` and inside it something like:

```
graphviz=~2.47.3
```

and your Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM python:3.8.6-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install
RUN pip install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /code
COPY /code
COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3", "<yourPythonScript>.py"]
EXPOSE 3000
COPY . .
```

To explain better, when your container is built, you should copy the `requirements.txt` file to the working directory of the docker container and then run the `pip install -r requirements.txt` command. This way, the graphviz package will be installed and accessible from its container.

Note: It's hard to understand without you showing us your Dockerfile.

Comment: Sorry for wasn't clear. The docker is already running. I want to add the package for a specific ad hoc usage. so I used `docker exec -it id bash` and did `pip install graphviz` and just ran a specific script. The scripts runs fine on my Mac but doesn't work on the docker

Comment: Now I get it. Did you try to list the packages installed in this container? If your container is based on Alpine use this: `docker exec -i <container_id> apk info -vv | sort`. If it is based on Debian & Ubuntu use this: `docker exec -i <container_id> dpkg -l`

Comment: pip freeze shows the package is installed but I guess the binary is missing. `pip install graphviz` isn't enough for some reason I need also to run `brew install graphviz` to get the binary but I don't know how to do that on a running docker.

Comment: Well, I think the solution would be to install the package in your image's Dockerfile, just as you suggested @DavidMaze